# Additive Persistence

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, repeated-transformation

*The shortest code to pass all possibilities wins.*

In mathematics, the [persistence of a number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number) measures how many times a certain operation must be applied to its digits until some certain fixed condition is reached.  You can determine the additive persistence of a positive integer by adding the digits of the integer and repeating.  You would keep adding the digits of the sum until a single digit number is found.  The number of repetitions it took to reach that single digit number is the additive persistence of that number.

**Example using 84523:**

```
84523
8 + 4 + 5 + 2 + 3 = 22
2 + 2 = 4

It took two repetitions to find the single digit number.
So the additive persistence of 84523 is 2.
```

You will be given a [sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) of positive integers that you have to calculate the additive persistence of.  Each line will contain a different integer to process.  Input may be in any [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/62402).

For each integer, you must output the integer, followed by a single space, followed by its additive persistence.  Each integer processed must be on its own line.

### Test Cases

---

**Input Output**

```
99999999999 3
10 1
8 0
19999999999999999999999 4
6234 2
74621 2
39 2
2677889 3
0 0
```

Comment: Your test cases include some values which are over 2^64, and your spec says that the program only has to handle values up to 2^32. Might be worth clearing that up.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, forgot to remove those limits.  If a program can handle the input I have provided, it shouldn't have an issue with limits.

Comment: Isn't 999999999999's persistence 2 instead of 3?

Comment: @Evelex, that was an incorrect last minute change I guess. Fixed.

Comment: Several answers here aren't doing output on stdout but rather use J's "interactive" output by returning results after taking command line input. (This includes 2 other J answers and, I'm guessing, the K answer.) Is this considered legit? Because I can shed 18-ish characters if so.

Comment: @Jesse Millikan, the problem doesn't state it must output to stdout.

Comment: It does state "followed by a single space," and, "on it's own line", which seems to imply at least some kind of string output. Also, interactive J doesn't format them as stated if there are inputs of different lengths.

Comment: "Also, interactive J doesn't format them as stated if there are inputs of different lengths."  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant outputs of different lenghts,  though it's  irrelevant... I was hallucinating or something. Both of the J answers are doing the output as given.

Comment: @Jesse Millikan, The K answer outputs a formatted string to stdout and not to the interactive prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### K - 29 Chars

Input is a filename passed as an argument, 29 chars not including filename.

```
`0:{5:x,-1+#(+/10_vs)\x}'.:'0:"file"
```

- 35 -> 31: Remove outside function.
- 31 -> 29: Remove parens.

Comment: `-1+#` => `#1_`

Answer (score 4):

**Python 84 Chars**

```
while 1:
 m=n=int(raw_input());c=0
 while n>9:c+=1;n=sum(map(int,str(n)))
 print m,c
```

Comment: Challenge case:`06234` .. result successful challenge :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Python (93 bytes)

```
f=lambda n,c:n>9and f(sum(map(int,str(n))),c+1)or c
while 1:n=int(raw_input());print n,f(n,0)
```

Comment: i think you can remove the space between `9` and err...`and`

Comment: and `input()` instead of `int(raw_input())`....

Comment: @st0le:Try this input with that modification:`06234`.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 100 characters

```
p[d]=0
p d=1+(p.show.sum$map((-48+).fromEnum)d)
f n=n++' ':shows(p n)"\n"
main=interact$(f=<<).lines
```

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by using `read.pure` instead of `(-48+).fromEnum`, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrRCoMgFADQ9/sVEkGKIFlROfJLtj3INIrl3SWLfb5jT3vZeT6LS8@wbTnT1d9tDcS81ZKTSsvrrdIZy@iI78F5RecehBcwM7QoZcWqyzclTgxFccMColvRrniE3T2Oks92moTaVgwpZ/MDuoYRtPkL@qbtYOj6RkNroOmHYRwN1B8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 15 bytes

<sub>+5 bytes for horrible I/O requirement</sub>

```
m(wΓ·,LU¡oΣdr)¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1ej/NzkQ9t1fEIPLcw/tzilSPPQtv///1siAJehAZcFl6ElVsBlZmRswmVuYmZkyGVsyWVkZm5uYWHJZQAA)

#### Explanation

To support multiple inputs, we need to use `m(₁r)¶` (where `₁` is the function doing the interesting computation):

```
m(₁r)¶  -- expects newline-separated inputs: "x₁␤x₂␤…␤xₙ"
     ¶  -- split on newlines: ["x₁","x₂",…,"xₙ"]
m(  )   -- map over each string
 ( r)   -- | read integer: [x₁,x₂,…,xₙ]
 (₁ )   -- | apply the function described below
```

The function `₁` does the following:

```
wΓ·,LU¡(Σd)  -- input is an integer, eg: 1234
      ¡(  )  -- iterate the following forever and collect results in list:
       ( d)  -- | digits: [1,2,3,4]
       (Σ )  -- | sum: 10
             -- : [1234,10,1,1,1,…
     U       -- keep longest prefix until repetition: [1234,10,1]
 Γ           -- pattern match (x = first element (1234), xs = tail ([10,1])) with:
  · L        -- | length of xs: 2
   ,         -- | construct tuple: (1234,2)
w            -- join with space: "1234 2"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### bash, 105 chars

```
while read x
do
for((i=0,z=x;x>9;i++))do
for((y=0;x>0;y+=x%10,x/=10))do :
done
x=$y
done
echo $z $i
done
```

Hardly any golfing actually involved, but I can't see how to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell - 114

```
s t n|n>9=s(t+1)$sum$map(read.(:[]))$show n|1>0=show t
f n=show n++" "++s 0n++"\n"
main=interact$(f.read=<<).lines
```

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using `pure` over `(:[])` and defining an operator instead of `s`, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxDoMgFEDR/X2FGgcICQE1Ion4JV1Ii9FUnwYwXfx3GtuhS@90pjvZ8HTLklLM8cRBGxKZpHk4VrLanXhnH3w/vKNlmLZXhvSUgzAfRxgz/BIZK7KCMZFfumEBq53RzBidt/dYkpFfJ9P3lC8zupCS/gVSQAdS/w3aqm5ANW0lodZQtUp1nQbxBg "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 85 Chars

```
puts $<.map{|n|v=n.chop!;c=0;[c+=1,n="#{n.sum-n.size*48}"] while n[1];[v,c]*' '}*"\n"
```

I had to borrow the "sum-size*48" idea from Alex, because it's just too neat to miss (in Ruby at least).

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript, 40 chars

```
n%{.:${;${48-}%{+}*`:$,}%.,1>\1?+' '\n}%
```

Answer (score 3):

### J - 45 Chars

Reads from stdin

```
(,' ',[:":@<:@#+/&.:("."0)^:a:)&><;._2(1!:1)3
```

Comment: I was trying to use `^:a:` myself but I couldn't find some proper documentation... any hints?

Comment: The [dictionary entry for u^:n](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm) has info on its usage but it is a bit dense. ^:a: is like any other call to power but it collects the results and ends when the argument to consecutive calls is the same(converges).

Comment: @Eelvex FWIW I discovered `a:` through the `^:a:` trick in the [J Reference Card](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/HenryRich?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=J602_RefCard_color_letter_current.pdf)[PDF]

Comment: @JB: That's the only reference on `^:a:` that I knew :D

Comment: @Eelvex Oh. I had the opposite experience then. I discovered the functionality in the dictionary, and used it as some variant of `^:(<'')` at first (probably for Kaprekar), until I spotted it in the card, and learned about `a:` for the occasion.

Answer (score 3):

### c -- 519

**(or 137 if you credit me for the framework...)**

Rather than solving just this one operation, I decided to produce a framework for solving **all persistence problems**.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef char*(*O)(char*);
char*b(char*s){long long int v=0,i,l=0;char*t=0;l=strlen(s);t=malloc(l+2);
for(i=0;i<l;i++)v+=s[i]-'0';snprintf(t,l+2,"%lld",v);return t;}
int a(char**s,O o){int r;char*n;n=o(*s);r=!strcmp(*s,n);free(*s);
*s=n;return r;}
int main(int c, char**v){size_t l, m=0;char *d,*n=0;O o=b;FILE*f=stdin;
while(((l=getline(&n,&m,f))>1)&&!feof(f)){int i=0;n=strsep(&n,"\n");
d=strdup(n);while(!a(&n,o))i++;printf("%s %d\n",d,i);free(d);free(n);n=0;m=0;}}
```

**Only the two lines starting from `char*b` are unique to this problem.**

It treats the input as strings, meaning that leading "0"s are not strip before the output stage.

The above has had comments, error checking and reporting, and file reading (input must come from the standard input) striped out of:

```c
/* persistence.c
 *
 * A general framework for finding the "persistence" of input strings
 * on opperations.
 *
 * Persistence is defined as the number of times we must apply
 *
 *    value_n+1 <-- Opperation(value_n)
 *
 * before we first reach a fixed point.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../getline.h"

/* A function pointer type for operations */
typedef char*(op_func)(char*);
typedef op_func* op_ptr;
/* Op functions must
 * + Accept the signature above
 * + return a point to a newly allocated buffer containing the updated str
 */

char* addop(char*s){
  int i,l=0;
  long long int v=0;
  char *t=NULL;
  /* protect against bad input */
  if (NULL==s) return s;
  /* allocate the new buffer */
  l = strlen(s);
  t = malloc(l+2);
  if (NULL==t) return t;
  /* walk the characters of the original adding as we go */
  for (i=0; i<l; i++) v += s[i]-'0';
  //fprintf(stderr,"   '%s' (%d) yields %lld\n",s,l,v);
  snprintf(t,l+2,"%lld",v);
  //fprintf(stderr,"   %lld is converted to '%s'\n",v,t);
  return t;
}

/* Apply op(str), return true if the argument is a fixed point fo
 * falsse otherwise,
 */ 
int apply(char**str, op_ptr op){ 
  int r;
  char*nstr;
  /* protect against bad input */
  if ( NULL==op ) exit(1); 
  if ( NULL==*str ) exit(4); 
  /* apply */
  nstr = op(*str); 
  /* test for bad output */
  if ( NULL==nstr ) exit(2); 
  r = !strcmp(*str,nstr); 
  /* free previous buffer, and reasign the new one */
  free(*str); 
  *str = nstr; 
  return r; 
}

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  size_t len, llen=0;
  char *c,*line=NULL;
  op_ptr op=addop;
  FILE *f=stdin;
  if (argc > 1) f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  while( ((len=getline(&line,&llen,f))>1) && line!=NULL && !feof(f) ){
    int i=0;
    line=strsep(&line,"\n"); // Strip the ending newline
    /* keep a copy for later */
    c = strdup(line);
    /* count necessary applications */
    while(!apply(&line,op)) i++;
    printf("%s %d\n",c,i);
    /* memory management */
    free(c);
    free(line);
    line=NULL;
    llen=0;
  }
}
```

A little more could be saved if we were willing to leak memory like a sieve. Likewise by `#define`ing return and the like, but at this point I don't care to make it any uglier.

Comment: [273 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY7RasMwDEXf/RVtRouduKNJQ5rguj@yjZHaTmqwlWC7fVjpt2c2G@xlFwTSlTi6YjcKsSwv2s6TCycfpJ5er2eUX7C49i735GEmGPNA73xPdSzDfXBGAfaEDZPDgdvemElgU1SE6ZNhHmanIQw40OjRbGOMzOi94P5NF8XHrm4JYU6Fm4NVYE@vv9RnWFmWS5oD1cz2GjB5JDgbVTAaFN4C3Vqa4gE5l9v1oKYB/4zMcuCar3@fZhu/2sh3yKikmpBEkSmyvM0YUuPVnHBZPIk5oiFs2lwwEBppMSJhz2Xp/oTKPWpR2f0r1FSHGh3rpirRoUNVczy2bYf26Bs "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```apl
{⍵≤9:0⋄1+∇+/⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

-4 bytes from Jo King.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qHeuJQIoGHMBBQwNFAxBtIWCAZhriRUomIAkzYyMTRSMQCxzEzMjQwjT2BJCG5mZm1tYQE01AJqm8ahvqlsQkAgI0HzUNsHQyMJcwdjkf/Wj3q2POpdYWhk86m4x1H7U0a6t/6i379CKR71TgVK1/9OAioECj7qaH/WuedS75dB640dtE4HmBAc5A8kQD8/g/2kKSI7jSlMwNAASFiAGdvcDZUCOB1JglwNpY5AY1M1AlgEA)

```apl
{s←+/⍎¨⍕⍵⋄⍵≤9:0⋄1+∇s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qHeuJQIoGHMBBQwNFAxBtIWCAZhriRUomIAkzYyMTRSMQCxzEzMjQwjT2BJCG5mZm1tYQE01AJqm8ahvqlsQkAgI0HzUNsHQyMJcwdjkf3UxkKOt/6i379CKR71TH/VufdTdAiI7l1haGQDZhtqPOtqLa/@nAdUBVT3qan7Uu@ZR75ZD640ftU0Emhcc5AwkQzw8g/@nKSA5kitNwdAASFiAGNj9AZQBeQJIgX0ApI1BYlC3A1kGAA)

### Explanation

```apl
{s←+/⍎¨⍕⍵⋄⍵≤9:0⋄1+∇s} ⍵ → input
       ⍕⍵             convert ⍵ to string
     ⍎¨               execute each character(getting digits)
   +/                 reduce to sum of digits
 s←                   assign to s
          ⍵≤9:        if number is single digit
              0       return 0, stop recursion
                1+∇s  Otherwise return 1+f(sum)
```

Comment: Bad habits.....

Answer (score 2):

### J, 74 chars

```
i=:<;._2(1!:1)3
i&((],' ',":@(0 i.~9<[:".([:":[:+/"."0)^:(i.9)))@>@{~)i.#i
```

#### Edits

- **(86 → 83)**  Some Caps `[:` to Ats `@`
- **(83 → 79)**  Unneeded parentheses
- **(79 → 75)**  Changing `0".` to `".` simplifies things
- **(75 → 74)**  Better Cutting

#### E.g

```
i=:<;._2(1!:1)3
74621
39
2677889
0
i&((],' ',":@(0 i.~9<[:".([:":[:+/"."0)^:(i.9)))@>@{~)i.#i
74621 2  
39 2     
2677889 3
0 0
```

Comment: Output  is formatted wrong for multiple inputs. See "single space"

Comment: @Jesse: I see nothing wrong. Could you write an example please?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm seeing things I guess.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x,#1_(+/10\)\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/7@6QkfZMF5DW9/QIEYzpqLWyMzc3MLCUuH/fwA)

**Explanation:**

```
{x,#1_(+/10\)\x} / the solution
{              } / lambda taking implicit x
      (     )\x  / iterate until convergence
         10\     / split into base-10 (123 => 1 2 3)
       +/        / sum
    1_           / drop first result (iterate returns input as first result)
   #             / count length of result
 x,              / prepend x (original input)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
żDS$Ƭ€Ẉ’ƊK€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oHpdglWNrHjWtebir41HDzGNd3kB25P///y0RQEfB0EBHwQJIWWIFOgpmRsYmOgrmJmZGhjoKxkABIzNzcwsLIMMAAA)

Takes input as a list of integers. [+3 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i1hh7Ye3eMSrHJszaOmNQ93dTxqmHmsyxvIjvz//7@SkpIlAnAZGnBZcBlaYgVcZkbGJlzmJmZGhlzGllxGZubmFhaWXAZAIwA) to input as a multiline string.

+3 bytes (or +6) for restrictive I/O formats, yay

### How it works

```
żDS$Ƭ€Ẉ’ƊK€Y - Main link. Takes a list l on the left
        Ɗ    - To l:
   $         -   Group the previous 2 links into a monad f(n):
 D           -     Digits
  S          -     Sum
    Ƭ€       -   Over each n in l, repeatedly apply f(n) until a fixed point,
                  yielding [n, f(n), f(f(n)), ...]
      Ẉ      -   Get the length of each loop
       ’     -   Decrement each
ż            - Zip the loop lengths with l
         K€  - Join each by spaces
           Y - Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `aj`, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ƛ⁽∑↔L‹"Ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhaiIsIiIsIsab4oG94oiR4oaUTOKAuVwi4bmEIiwiIiwiOTk5OTk5OTk5OTlcbjEwXG44XG4xOTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OVxuNjIzNFxuNzQ2MjFcbjM5XG4yNjc3ODg5XG4wIl0=)

Explanation:

```
          # Treat all the inputs as a list (`a` flag)
ƛ         # On each item (n) in that list
 ⁽        # Create a single element lambda
  ∑       # That sums the digits of a number
   ↔      # Apply that function on n until it doesn't change 
          # and return the intermediate values in a list
    L     # Get the length of that list
     ‹    # Decrement it to ignore the last time the function is called
      "   # Pair that with n
       Ṅ  # Join the pair by a space
          # Join the mapped inputs by new lines (`j` flag)
          # Implicitly print
```

Comment: @Steffan Dammit, I misread those rules.

Comment: @Steffan I don't think the `İ` approach works, for 8 it outputs 1 but it should be 0

Comment: Steffan's approach works with the `A` flag.

Comment: @emanresuA Hmm, can you show me?

Comment: Wait nvm, that separates by `‍ => ‍`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about the best I can come up with.

**Ruby 101 Chars**

```
f=->(n){n.sum-n.size*48}
$<.each{|l|i=0;i+=1 while(i+=1;n=f[(n||l.chop!).to_s])>10
puts "#{l} #{i}"}
```

Comment: Actually, chop! instead of chomp! gives me a one character savings. 97 chars.

Comment: Just did some more golfing at it - 91 chars.

Answer (score 1):

**PARI/GP 101 Chars**

```
s(n)=r=0;while(n>0,r+=n%10;n\=10);r
f(n)=c=0;while(n>9,c++;n=s(n));c
while(n=input(),print(n," ",f(n)))
```

<strike>Unfortunately, there's no input function for GP, so i guess this lacks the IO part. :(</strike> 
Fixed: Thanks Eelvex! :)

Comment: Sure there is: `input()` :)

Comment: @Eelvex, done. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript - 95**

```
i=prompt();while(i>9){i=''+i;t=0;for(j=0;j<i.length;j++)t+=parseInt(i.charAt(j));i=t;}alert(t);
```

EDIT: Whoops does'nt do the multi-lines

Comment: Just noticed this doesn't output it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 78

```
f=:[:+/"."0&":
r=:>:@$:@f`0:@.(=f)
(4(1!:2)~LF,~[:":@([,r)".@,&'x');._2(1!:1)3
```

Recursive solution. Reads from stdin. **Writes to stdout**, so cut me some slack - it does take an extra 18-ish characters.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl - 77 characters

```
sub'_{split//,shift;@_<2?0:1+_(eval join'+',@_)}chop,print$_,$",(_$_),$/for<>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### scala 173:

```
def s(n:BigInt):BigInt=if(n<=9)n else n%10+s(n/10)
def d(n:BigInt):Int=if(n<10)0 else 1+d(s(n))
Iterator.continually(readInt).takeWhile(_>0).foreach(i=>println(i+" "+d(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), <s>57</s> 47 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to @l4m2!*

```javascript
f=(s,c=0)=>s>9?f(eval([...s+""].join`+`),++c):c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDRCoMgFAbg@z1FeKXYTC0sB7YHGYPCVRSRY45e39XVwqz/@jv/4ZyhnmurP/37e53Mq3GuVdDGWlGkSlvKewubuR7hgxBiMQBPMph@qnCFYow1ummnzWTN2JDRdLCFQP4DEIq2SZIovXicUV9tOfN5cahXTnftMpi1ZOGZzwVPs4MFC@c@zzPBWdiHeCrPTt1xLvK8KIIzoUfS88@4Hw)

Comment: ```f=(s,c=0)=>s>9?f([...s+""].reduce((x,y)=>x*1+y*1),++c):c```

Comment: ```f=(s,c=0)=>s>9?f([...s+""].reduce((x,y)=>x- -y),++c):c```

Comment: ```f=(s,c=0)=>s>9?f(eval([...s+""].join`+`)),++c):c```

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks! `s>9` and `eval` were great ideas. I think you had an extra paren in there, making it a total of 10 bytes you saved me :-)

Comment: Note the strict I/O ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-R`, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
Ë+S+(DsÊÉ ÆD=ìxÃâ Ê
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=yytTKyhEc8rJIMZEPex4w+Igyg==&input=Wzg0NTIzLDk5OTk5OTk5OTk5LDEwLDgsNjIzNCw3NDYyMSwzOSwyNjc3ODg5LDBdCi1S)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ε.ΓSO}g}ø»
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@Steffan*

Input as a list of integers.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Fa9c5OD/WvTaw/vOLT7//9oSwTQMTTQsdAxtMQKdMyMjE10zE3MjAx1jC11jMzMzS0sLHWAOkxMjYxjAQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
ε      # Map each integer in the (implicit) input to:
 .Γ    #  Loop until the integer no longer changes,
       #  keeping all intermediate steps in a list:
   S   #   Convert the integer to a list of digits
    O  #   Sum those digits together
  }g   #  After the inner loop: pop and push the length
}ø     # After the outer map: zip/transpose it with the (implicit) input to create a
       # list of pairs
  »    # Join each pair by a space, and then the list of strings by newlines
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: 10 bytes: [`ε.ΓSO}g}ø»`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Fa9c5OD/WvTaw/vOLT7//9oSwTQMTTQsdAxtMQKdMyMjE10zE3MjAx1jC11jMzMzS0sLHWAOkxMjYxjAQ "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 11 bytes

```
hÅ_Σ]▀£(k ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/jcGv8ucWxj6Y1HFqska1g//@/JQJwGRpwWXAZWmIFXGZGxiZc5iZmRoZcxpZcRmbm5hYWllwG/wE)

<s>Incredibly inefficient, but we don't care about that. Basically, using the fact that the additive persistence of a number is smaller than or equal to the number itself.</s>

Uses the fact that the additive persistence is less than or equal to the number of digits of the number. Passes all test cases with ease now.

The input format, while suboptimal for some languages, is actually the standard method of taking multiple test cases as input in MathGolf. Each line of the input is processed as its own program execution, and output is separated by a single newline for each execution.

### Explanation (using `n = 6234`)

```
h             push length of number without popping (6234, 4)
 Å            loop 4 times using next 2 operators
  _           duplicate TOS
   Σ          get the digit sum
    ]         wrap stack in array
              this gives the array [6234, 15, 6, 6, 6]
     ▀        unique elements of string/list ([6234, 15, 6])
      £       length of array/string with pop (3)
       (      decrement (2)
        k ?   push input, space, and rotate top 3 elements to produce output (6234 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 92 (29) bytes

```
f(n)=n>9&&(f∘sum∘digits)(n)+1
```

Edit:
With correct printing it's 92:

```
f(n)=n>9&&(f∘sum∘digits)(n)+1
while(n=parse(Int128,readline()))≢π
println("$n ",f(n)%Int)end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>8</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ªwæMε∞ö?îm⌐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a677914deeec943f8c6da9&i=99999999999%0A10%0A8%0A19999999999999999999999%0A6234%0A74621%0A39%0A2677889%0A0&a=1)

+3 bytes thanks to  @Khuldraeseth (the first answer didn't have compliant output)

Comment: I reached the same solution, but with `i` in place of `u`. Adhering to the draconian IO specifications, this becomes [11 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a677914deeec943f8c6da9&i=99999999999%0A10%0A8%0A19999999999999999999999%0A6234%0A74621%0A39%0A2677889%0A0).

Comment: Oops.  I guess I didn't read the IO requirements very well.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-r`, 52 bytes

```perl
[while(length>1;explode|map(.-48)|add|@text)]|length

-r                    # take one number per line, converting it to a string

                explode                              # the character codes
                       |map(.-48)                    # subtract ascii zero from each
                                 |add                # sum the elements
                                     |@text          # back to text, (shorter than
                                                     # tostring and tojson)
 while(length>1;                           )         # produces *all* the intermediate
                                                     # results while the string length>1
[                                           ]        # collected into an array
                                             |length # the length of these results
```

Not answering the multiplicative persistence now because jq doesn't have a `product` builtin :)

[Jq play it!](https://jqplay.org/s/HjHvWmd9d7)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 54 bytes

```
;=iP;=r 0;W<1Li;=s 0;Wi;=s+sA Ai=iGi 1Li;=i+""s=r+1rOr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltV9vKEf5s/4rFOdhavySSoOfcWsgckgscTgnkQtJ8ADcRsgx7KsuuJMOlhP71dGb2RSvbpE17@SBpd@f12dmZWRMPbuP4@yuRxelykuwV5UTMX9@NmvZMKm5qU3H5uEhWiHKR3damSjGTNJNkKrKEpSlL59ktPZpm9uPZp/fMq4aXHy@YXw3/enDBdqvh0dk79ks1vPjEvIr46PTSoj37dGqRfjp7f3D5F6fgzMFHm/3L@xM3qweXoFYuxndRzrq8YrCpwFYjYjRiu9Xa2eFnXMxgkTz6xvB7b2@FBtUQDboJNGnKkbBG8/b8/JSI8LFPTg7RN8uQi2NJAPyWrfdRukw4v8rGvNkkP2BXrsbhRevw/Mj5HoTiQxDmzA0@73mnIggL/MR3rzhgByIUx4LRgui1WkWY97z8PP/OgbkVSHldEJhEMxai5KDZBPWLKC8Sh7OnZkNkJRNBswGzZEqfdafLLIYZYo5hXM4W/WKRXfnj8Mntu88goyFAHNHD28WJN29QvFiwhztRJsUiipNmA77TxIF5YHekGX3Wui6vs@vpdc6enq/GDh@@anEypSGmzDHWhqzzqsOZFKFnt2D2OoPpXk/OgJ2NJC0Se@JZmhPfJfHf2XSes2w5u0nyQtnDHFFMxK0otVTQju54feORfHeZ57Ie6yrLez3OBqzjdkAFWio4y5NymWdMB49ko/gJVm24j3IR3aSJtgKMSOcPSe7EoE8bwr59Y9q4mEYxAfGlwxU8YoPrIvT6sEehmV6xDo@jClsgySbLhYNbyhSmAwajdYNlciikNGnGdadT2dTqyE0DZvDAGMVACCQT@AbLFlFRsvIuAWFRXgKx2oCuRhQ3NOboiTbWOmMvGgtPj9NGNyowyHwM3VLMMzAbI9Ydg2mxRqRYLhYIONdRpWds@O34A9gtsFGGDuVFBnEMiQ0jV1kuUfnYMadfThzhBCa5ISY3NFMHGeVF6aqDdqOpUZrOY2fX7XscHcRp4wQ5mC3TNMofbUer/bmwtudDx1hGChX/MlvhJhUeqlBJYZOnB4dv3339bev013PLYVvsjdgo11@Xu1UTfHxy@YLEMslJZJRN2D@WkR6i2Htbxc66CgnAccdgcbIBC2LerTPXaZ4pVebLDHcoUMm5W84LR@dKOgAQ2qWIGa3eLKdX/u5Y2SE3uk3pwRhQLOBYlVMHSMH/7TSdtHTeoeLURyGrAuBQGAGy7En9Nbo95u3U/UTnMRb3WavMl0kLYtDMY0jC/DSCDIILLYysVgUC@om@q/pEcHx5O5@nsHJTR@BFXyu3fuRQ9@c9ss28WTMzRRuzP9RGCNpynqaObWqfuX2oEP@DydmayViF3x98OOtjLZaBBsOTK891XQgncAWGelSIfyZfSoavwIpRy1tEAEZ9fPj03Ak9XdIxw2FVxxc9ffnaAYKjk9PDLptCcgwaJrSVPkzDcbTop0lGHYCFlW6fJGZw7l4CY5URaxOWNiw4jqBeAmrxHmERQFERuGjyRjxbrOwAgSTGVQpBmMQY1RQPoozvnC4gs9ZtAUZM/cVYpzoHnSFDLZIgRECxX4MszNvklBKvOsZayPKAqnBFQW1pmWPpos70asyfqjCDBopyu1R8AYrrsnPIeA5vu79P8a@i/ACUIFVidJuUKTSVTpv2so07hCVyIjIeiKnj0H5iQxDf5WhLH@KUc7nNoRtstBVenNoAqe9Q6pOdI2YDBUig7UWQVO6srHxb@SPpzcq7agU5bYgNzVegwWiA@AsX80WSOZbifitvUasAVoUzWSkhHkPf3f2F5lVz4ciOZAqmT9ApaOEgZPvY3wE59A40Qh2gWoeXA5OsF1IrhCcWKLmCG@SQLoIaJXRD5ts9SwVj5clv4EnyO7RxeNrX/Nyq7TrdHbYwk60Rnq6FB2hJ67hY5L92hqpP3BDIJvOpCtQ6o7bYwRrEdREajXZ51ViupUPNeknNobNdIGP9MKwzA5zQ@th6IZPyVkWqF7C8JFGmxL5UwlTNsndA5RaFwnmFAh4MefFB0OR@1qBj7TZduAYDJB3LNvea2u2GNmv7dbcAexwYcaaPWm6ZvywLvfsmJmSvJw3qGYMoT0K@xJSMoWVtj@ymG/XdlrdXpIa@n@lY8uWeY/9Lh0FuAFHhNJ7yUHvp882hGkelfqmu0@tVMHH9jbI4dKN9epcqRyi/BmvRaUU7tup1eyVTt9qdDSislucNOHTXcJD7ugmF2QbXukQT2kKIAWqQQxky7FzDJQ@JgsGA5CmgqGSubrREtKyd/jc/BObNZmC2f8i0vZnpb4RmzSF5daA53/YyULBL1EM28AzKRAvQe3DOBh6cMc8m9n@Seg/SY402DJGU9A71jKshJ6D9kauw9jm1K92Q8G@uHghaJFfgjkAJFksMfOOV4S7Jk07Bsjn00CItRcYeokfAjU3mcCctk9skB57FPEuyUkR4i4CTPGcPCbuL7hMgVIKQvGSzKFtC@Dy@xln07gYRBygIiWKZlvijASk3CU@TDGwarXIFMpvPkKyIR3kvU7ovG2LI9mpULt3PoxRr4yN4nU3SZMK@VmZ/NVKe8Es2ZpaSypkRChsM9JgTeUORdi3Tn00e3KNgXSl8mPRqeTGsZ8V9Zh/@PfsYIOtQ/S7XZpJgn9UaRZrsMysbogxXcuqS68s6gLRbIVQbqwsawaHE0JpP5kM2S2bxAsMsY6Ov@/@vK6M/wJWRdmVrgy@h8kW5sv8y@lLrBpNxeZ/VCHxD4esCurXJzmpg3NOZxxZgzGtX6Q992VQb9m1OlUoM/7f/hl/lIEuM4Q86Q5u61uau0oZV1q0v//RFRve21U0G6Rq124xJhUSDEsdhjdtKk8iBFL2eYZMmfwb35K9edqNZ847ZvYtiO6l37Uhq8e/7wx0LlmN5ZQitDqtnF6D1O1KmLh59cxZ2ag3tpQR6RWiwWvL8TSVvh5s@wDfcuzT5HxoiNAzfuBWxaf5NO2T3Rj54iFp7HjZJ1CDI@JeL9CKKnjoJoH2STCNIkuCZ7jBFBotiQj8iRXEJZaqzHXew58QZzl64xaIwUwOhG1Q/JMwikWGzyqL8Nu6T0G4Xvu85/lxF90v8N4/jkjX1a9zzd@/PG//@DQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 21 bytes

```
0s+1[pSy,![lu;]&+l`s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9@gWNswuiC4UkcxOqfUOlZNOyehOBYoDAA)

A pretty straight forward interpretation of the challenge rules this time.

```
0s+1[pSy,![lu;]ç]
0s                    - initialize the backup cell to 0 (iteration count)
  +                   - load input number, absorbing the 0 on the stack
   1                  - push a truthy value to enter loop
    [p              ] - infinite loop
      S               - convert number on top of stack to digits
       y              - push the number of digit (stack size)
        `!            - decrement and convert truthiness
          [   ]       - if/then, executes is number is a single digit
           lu;        - load backup cell, print as number, end program
               &+     - sum the digits on the stack
                 l`s  - load backup cell (iterations) increment and save
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 95 bytes

```
proc P {v n\ 0} {set V $v
while \$v>9 {set v [expr [join [split $v ""] +]]
incr n}
puts $V\ $n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY69CoMwAIT3e4pDsnXxDzVLn8HJRR2KCE1J06BpWpA8exro0KXfeNzHnVt0jHZ7LOx5eJqJeeCxr44DhcfrqvTKSfiz/Kae4/q2G8fbQxmOu9XKpSKzbOZpnqHMstEE2KfbKYaJwoSo7xebzAPyB1Hk6FDIv6Apqxpt3ZQFKomyaduuk8iRzvVpL8QP)

Comment: Because the next newest answer is a full 6 years old, which i think is before TIO existed

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>87</s> 85 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); pulling the `t=s` assignment forward and using `(t=s)[1]` ~ `*((t=s)+1)` ~ `*(1+(t=s))` ~ `1[t=s]`.

```c
f(n,p){char*t,s[99];for(p=0;sprintf(s,"%d",n),1[t=s];p++)for(n=0;*t;n+=*t++-48);n=p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5BC4MgHAXw8/YpJAg0DdSiDJF9kNYhHG0d9p@kt@izO4PO9c6/93i2fFsb44SBObLaz7gUgfm@6wY9/RbsDNfeLTOECXuW5a@MAWGiD8YP2lFKdgQJFUEDNUWgtKwV0WCc3uJ3nAGT9X47FlIfPQzKX0/IGJow2iM4YUgQfa6QSoqfq0ZWdVLyVLV1I8WlSqm6CyWbtlVqV9Xle3683@If)

Comment: @ceilingcat That is quite neat.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 65 bytes

```perl
$b=0;$q=s/\n//r;$_=eval s/./+$&/gr while y///c>1&&++$b;say"$q $b"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lydbAWqXQtlg/Jk9fv8haJd42tSwxR6FYX09fW0VNP71IoTwjMydVoVJfXz/ZzlBNTVtbJcm6OLFSSaVQQSVJ6f9/Q0usgMvY6F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/unkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 79 bytes

```java
a->{int d=0;while(a/10>0){int c=0;d++;while(a>0){c+=a%10;a/=10;}a=c;}return d;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pU7LbsIwELzzFXupZCsiOLQiIMv8AcqBY9XD1nZb0@BEzpqqQv721IG2N05cRqt57MwBTzjveusP5nPULQ4D7ND58wzAebLhDbWF5pxvCGxC5DJlcSAkp6GBJlIfCRSMON9efEYJ@fXhWstwUYmt4BdWZ9YUxZ8y0bpQ@FAJiQuVMaHSMgVLMXgwMo0y1/Txtc01v22nzhk45nlsT8H59@cX5NNSgP33QPZYdpHKPivUenYdVga2Wj4@cS5v@W4r/x8qcV9@uarr9Xpz35P6Gk@zNP4A)

There's probable potential to golf it further, but I'll look into that in the future, but for now, I'm pretty happy with this little result.

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY7BbsIwEETvfMVekGwFgkMrQmU5f4By4Fj1sNgGmQYnctZIFcq3p06puHHislrtzLydM15x2XbWn833qBvse9ih87cZgPNkwxG1hfqWdghsmsjlkMSekJyGGupIXSRQMOKy@vMZJRZaHtvAJK4KUTGtBJeoNJ9uJsskViJJqhBcZwrnhZDBUgwejBxGmehdPDSJ/v/k2joDl9SK7Sk4f/r8Qj4VBNj/9GQveRsp75JCjWf3Pnlgm/XbO@fyme@58iCkfi/l15uy3G4/XoOU9/gwG8Zf).

Comment: Building on @JonathanFrech [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY7BbsIwDIbvPIUvk5J1dIEhCrLCG0w9cJx28JIwhZW0Sh2kCfXZu3RMu3HiYtn@f//@jnSmedu5cLRfo2mo7@GVfLjMAHxgFw9kHNSX3EMUUyWJQxZ7JvYGaqgTd4lBw0jz3a/PavVk8NBGgbTbImkjp8Fo9WiLIu8U0rNeKGkKTQ8LhdFxigEsDiPm6C59NDn678O59RZOGUnsOfrw@fZOcqID2H/37E5lm7jsssJNEFeYMor18mUlJd7y3Vb@EzLfXffLdVVtNtv7Qqrr@TAbxh8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## **Python 3**, 82 bytes

```
while 1:f=lambda n:n//10and 1+f(sum(map(int,str(n))));i=input();print(i,f(int(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 28 bytes

```js
Ë+S+(@D=X©A<D©ì x ªD D<AÃaÃ·
Ë                            // Map over the inputs and return each, followed by
 +S+                         // a space, followed by the number's persistence.
      D=     ©ì x            // To find it, fold the number up
        X©A<D     ªD         // if we can (handles unfoldable cases),
    (@               D<AÃa   // until it can't be folded up any further.
                          Ã· // Then, join everything up with newlines.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qYXB0///DiytTKyhARD1YwqlBPETCqcOsIHggwqpEIEQ8QcODYcODwrf//1sxMjksOCwgMjY3Nzg4OV0)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 72+1 bytes

+1 for `-R` flag.

```
for($i=0,$a=$argn;$a>9;$i++)$a=array_sum(str_split($a));echo"$argn $i
";
```

Run as pipe with `-R`.

- running PHP as pipe will execute the code once for every input line
- but it does not unset variables inbetween; so `$i` must be initialized.
  (Also, it would print nothing instead of `0` for single digits without the initialization.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)+coreutils, 83 bytes

```bash
[ $1 -le 9 ]&&exit $2
let x=$2+1
for z in `fold -w1<<<$1`
do let y+=$z
done
a $y $x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9Nb8IwDL3nVzyVCIFQES2IjwGattN22g7cJiQy6qoZIUFpGIVpv71zTlzmg/2eP57tT1VXbefZaUP@ZFQg7F1BCA7@bOEsNq9v@DrXAUYfCKqGLqEDLuQJ2iJUhJMKlaDm5HzA@9PmZZ3InidVGG0PSEswLbS36kgMR0k/6T/I2JcI1vqA7CC1hBG2yyhnW05lSA1hgW23Sw2vk7kwFNCsZT7IROk8bnH7rnSmQHrJVquVzHaicIht18Fa3phYEgryCtm0nUD8w17VVAsyNYnjN4bx1WHQDkqUvT5@on6GJXio4UD7ykUkH5n8ihKLuzHLRuzmESz@Na5M8/GEw2wyzflqjGMun85m83lEPK/bPw)

Should be saved to a script called `a` and placed in the system's `PATH`, as it calls itself recursively. Takes input from command line, like `a 1999`. Returns by exit code.

TIO has some limitations on what you can do with a script, so there's some boilerplate code to make this run in the header.

Prints an error to `stderr` for input larger than bash integers can handle, but since the actual computation is done with strings, it still gives the right result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
def f(n,i=0,p=0):p=p or n;f(sum(map(int,str(n))),i+1,p)if n>9else print(p,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYm7DgIhFER7v4Ly3kjBYwPsGvwXEyGSuOwNYOHXo9DYOMXMyRx6t8eRde/3EFmEzJMXnLzAjTyxo7B8iVBfO@w3gpQbr61ARkSezpITpsjydQ3PGhiVrwfiCXuE9Rc8RZBitJu4/s1QRullrF2MkgP0vJWx1rmJAvsH)

---

Without I/O restrictions:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:f(sum(map(int,str(n))),i+1)if n>9else i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY29DgIhEIR7n4JyN1IccOHH5HwXjEfc5EByYOHT4zXGLZzum2@Sqe/@eBYzRlq2mG/3KIqkZbokaK8MOVag0mXrOxRElHRWSEmUa1i3tgoadT88JAi/IJ6@rZoYeC7C37CF1WZm6GarFWPDt9o65z1vjt/xAQ)

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5, 106 bytes

```
func a(_ s:S,_ i:I)->(S,I){if s.count<=1{return(s,i)};return a(S(s.compactMap{I(S($0))}.reduce(0,+)),i+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVJNa@MwEL3rVwwmBw11g52EfLibXkoLPvTkvTUlCEduxTq2kMbsFuPfnp04Cd4uuZXOQR9Pb2b0HuN/m4JmB7O3tSN4qptqp8jUlRClJiDt6UF5DWsIgkCshoCpiCOIxRIiEa@uBszEfDKdwUQsZvNJzPt0xctkvlgsl8cCEecey4qiqXLI33X@6yc3lFvwCWTkTPUWwhaKBOTlllaEcHv/GUBoBXBYhkj6/nyMsbelYUBb5RTVLoFgUwU4vO@VhRZG0RUiBAjdwFRlmbEvvvjghFNvWZw/IUfRS/SKIUQ4jhHWaxjw@JXLoOjOGukr8r5FWFG7R5W/M/vkXuC0b0pKNrS5JhA3pP9YnZPe9ZRPSrEvzVrpw2pVGuUhg4sb/4Apgyzs0Fuiej@ycAsmSfH2XmZhiq0pwI9znkb6sY5bp6lxlfShwe7udOG8TB4pe6tyela2TRkY8Q@7sdO7JtcyCm8QQ3MTY3cYhusy0iEoFPQ/cvgL)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 62 bytes

```
f=lambda x,i=0:f(`sum(int(i)for i in x)`,i+1)if len(x)>1else i
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:0if n<10else-~f(eval('+'.join(str(n))))
```

Recursive function. Takes an integer, returns an integer.

**Explanation:**

```python
# create a lambda function which takes one argument, and assign it to f
f=lambda n:\
    # if n is 0-9, it's persistence 0
    0if n<10\
        # otherwise, add one to the running total and recursively call f
        # ( ~ will invert the returned number, equivalent to -n-1)
        # (negating that gives you -(-n-1) = n+1)
        else-~f(
            # convert integet to string, join each character with a '+'
            # gives a string like '1+2+3+4+...+n'
            # evaluate the string as an expression, giving a new integer
            # pass that integer back into f
            eval('+'.join(str(n)))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
FG.Qs[Gdtl.usjNTG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/381dL7A42j2lJEevtDjLL8T9/39LBOAyNOCy4DK0xAq4zIyMTbjMTcyMDLmMLbmMzMzNLSwsuQwA)

If I can instead of values on different lines, take a list of numbers (in the format `[9999999999, 10, 8, etc.]`), then -1 byte by replacing `.Q` with `Q`

```
F                  # For
 G.Q               #   G in the complete input (split by newlines)
    s[             #     join the list as string, create list from the following values:
      Gd           #       G, " " (for output formatting),
        tl         #       decrement length of
          .u    G  #          List of all intermediate results until there's a returning result, with starting value G
            s      #            reduce on + (add all list elements) the list:
             j     #              convert to integer as list:
              N    #                The current value (implicit input to .u)
               T   #                in base 10 (T=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 36 bytes

```
0{:a(7$.0}\~1+!
~n
1:,a}+{%a:/?(1:-%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36DaKlHDXEXPoDamzlBbkasuj8vQSiexVrtaNdFK317D0EpX9f///7plRmbm5hYWlgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7 bytes (14 nibbles)

```
:$,>>`.$/`@~$+
```

```
                    # (implicitly map over input):
:$                  # prepend input onto
  ,                 # length  
   >>               # (without first item) of
     `.             # iterate while unique
       $            # starting with input number:
         `@~$       #   convert to base-10 digits
        /           #   and fold over this list
             +      #     adding its elements
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 77 bytes

```go
func f(n int)int{s:=0
if n<10{return 0}
for;n>0;n/=10{s+=n%10}
return 1+f(s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDhSsMwEMfxa57iLBQSjFvbja3rzEDQj4pov6lo2ZpR5tKSpqCEPolfhuBD-Cj6NF7WiggGkvw57v73u3t9W5e7jypbbrJ1DtusUKTYVqU2A09ujffeGHkcf17IRi1BUgWFMgyvrRMRkEKCOgkDq3PTaAVBS2Sp52oRzNVQYLw-EsoPMdwnhEeS1qztTL8OHs1LlUMKtdHN0oAtVMUhf65ck5aQfU9HRBlYYvLa1JAIuL1PLbGz38Nh1HJiw4BD6ETMkYST4dCGs38Ph7HLm0SjMYfIyel4EoW9Hs16EU2m0zj-sQ86V-QiVxoBnxT1hBBwk55ep4DKY256eOAmETpTuM0O2ZIMh0NwSc0AR2RubeUmERgWwgxw4Dkclhuwe19JPX8FYgH4Un_FwDd3yuOwr-WARU5jEUcT1iLQHxw4vzyDHqdf9G7X_d8)