# How Persistent am I?

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that, when given a number, outputs its *persistence*.  The persistence of a number is the number of times you can add its digits before arriving at a one-digit number.  All one digit numbers have a persistence of 0.  Note that this is different from questions about finding the digital root, as those questions ask for the end result of this process, whereas this question wants the number of steps required to get there.

### Input:

An integer.

### Output:

The persistence of the inputted integer.

### Examples:

```
1-->0 (1=1)
12-->1 (1+2=3)
99-->2  (9+9=18, 1+8=9)
9999-->2 (9+9+9+9=36, 3+6=9)
```

### Scoring:

This is  [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: [Relevant OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A031286)

Comment: *Highest* score in bytes wins?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how neither I nor the sandbox caught that.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1775/47066).

Comment: @Emigna That was posted in 2011. It also requires a stricter IO format.

Comment: @Okx: The 2 challenges are exactly the same. The only difference is that you could check the persistence of more than 1 number at once in the other challenge. It may be better to close that challenge as a duplicate, but I would argue that they are the same.

Comment: I do agree that they are the same, but I didn't catch that when checking for dupes, and neither did anyone in the sandbox.  That one is rather old, and this one already has 7 answers, so I would say close the old one, but if you want to close this one, feel free.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista, I'm feeling generous, so sure.

Comment: Any language using 64 bit ints or less will only ever output `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. I believe the first `4` is at **19999999999999999999999** (one followed by twenty-two nines).

Comment: No, you can't dup an old question to a new question. That would set an awful precedent

Comment: Sorry - I used my dup hammer.  But if ever there were an open-and-shut dup case, this is it, IMO

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: You definitely *can* dupe backwards, typically in cases when there's something seriously wrong with the old challenge and the new challenge covers the same space better. It's probably inadvisable unless the old challenge is broken, though.

Comment: @ais523 Agreed - there are special cases when it is OK, but I don't think this is one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
DS$ÐĿL’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98lWOXwhCP7fR41zPx/uP1R05r//6MNdQyNdCwtgcjSMhYA)

### How it works

```
DS$ÐĿL’
DS$      digital sum
   ÐĿ    apply until results not unique, collect all intermediate results
     L   length of the collection
      ’  minus 1
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>50</s> 39 bytes

-10 thanks to @JonathanAllan

```python
f=lambda x:x>9and-~f(sum(map(int,`x`)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoAgEADP9Yq9SCsYVNBhg3pLRkhBmqTBdunrZjBzmvFP3E7XpWTGQ9tl1cADT6TdWr8Gw23Rao@7i2rmWUqZzHkBw@4y/o4oh7LwV@5QiT6ACJVAVgY5r42CtlNA9Ev0AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
;.{ẹ+}ⁱ⁾Ḋ∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/31qv@uGundq1jxo3Pmrc93BH16OO5f//WwLB/ygA)

#### Explanation

```
;.{  }ⁱ⁾     Iterate Output times on the Input…
        Ḋ∧   …so that the result is a single digit:
   ẹ+          Sum the elements
```

Comment: 10/10 declarative much.

Answer (score 5):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```
s(A,B):-A=0,B=0;divmod(A,10,Q,R),s(Q,T),B is T+R.
p(A,B):-A<10,B=0;s(A,S),p(S,T),B is T+1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/v1jDUcdJ00rX0dZAx8nWwDolsyw3PwUoaGigE6gTpKlTrBGoE6Kp46SQWawQoh2kx1UA02FjCNECMiJYU6dAIxhJoaHe//8FGoY6jiAJQyOgDiBtaanjDKGBLBdNPQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 58 bytes

1 byte thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista and [Kritixi Lithos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38132712#38132712) who discovered the same golf independently.

```c
a,m;f(n){for(m=n,a=0;m;m/=10)a+=m%10;return n>9?1+f(a):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dclBDsIgEEDRtZ6C1DQZUlRwh0i9iBsCRUmcqUG6anp2NHFbl/99v797X3eJ/HMKA7u8S0jj4dFXJ9BEID7HMQNaEs5KgwaPVknuOoutkiYPZcrEqNdX1UVw/CzNUhMVhi4R8Hm7eeVvRmjacKNGRFCcmxU9rbLWf/g3lvoB)

Comment: `n>9?1+f(a):0;` for 1 byte

Comment: On gcc, [`a,m;f(n){for(m=n,a=0;m;m/=10)a+=m%10;n=n>9?1+f(a):0;}`](https://tio.run/##dclBCsIwEEDRtZ6iVAozNGriLo6pF3ETEqMBZyq1rkrPHgW3dfnfD9tbCGWTJTze8VqdXmPM/e7eFa@YEghOqR@AnSjvNDHx3hmNvnXcGE3ipLNn0ybweNQ0lyxjxT4L4LRePYdvJqibeJFaJTCItKCHRbb2D//GXD4) works.

Comment: @Steadybox No, you can't convince me to write a function without the return statement.

Comment: @LeakyNun I guess your persistence fits the spirit of the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
(n=#;t=0;While[n>9,n=Tr@IntegerDigits@n;t++];t)&
```

but **alephalpha** golfed it down to...

## Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
(t=-1;#//.n_:>Tr[t++;IntegerDigits@n];t)&
```

Comment: `(t=-1;#//.n_:>Tr[t++;IntegerDigits@n];t)&`

Comment: very nice. posted!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
[DgiNq}SO
```

Explanation:

```
[          Start infinite loop
 D         Duplicate
  g        Length
   i       If equal to one:
    N        Push iteration number
     q       Terminate program
      }    Else:
       S     Get the characters
        O    Sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2iU906@wNtj//39LIAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```hs
g n|m<-sum$read.pure<$>show n,m<n=1+g m|1<3=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcc7DoAgEAXA3lO8gs5PRCsS8C4kEiSyqwGNDXfHWqebzebdxVirBxfSfb5JJGfX4byT02LJ2/GAO9JsZOtBRerZjJVsYBisBxoAZwp8QcBD/jp9r9T/StUX)

`read.pure<$>show n` converts an integer `n` to a list of digits, applying `sum` to this list yields the digital sum `m`. If `m` is smaller than `n` then `n` was not yet a single digit, so we recursively call `g m` and add one. Otherwise `0` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 47 bytes

```
f=x=>x>9?f([...x+""].reduce((a,b)=>+a+ +b))+1:0
```

```js
f=x=>x>9?f([...x+""].reduce((a,b)=>+a+ +b))+1:0

console.log('1 -> ' + f(1));
console.log('12 -> ' + f(12));
console.log('99 -> ' + f(99));
console.log('9999 -> ' + f(9999));
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 67 bytes

```
n->{int r=0,s;for(;n>9;n=s,r++)for(s=0;n>0;n/=10)s+=n%10;return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hVDLCsIwELz3K/YiJFRr65MS4h/Yi0fxEGOUaN2WJBWk9Ntror1KDzuwM8PssHfxErOqVni/PHpZCmthLzS2EYBGp8xVSAVFWL8ESBIQKfNMF3mwTjgtoQAEDj3Odm0wGJ5OLbtWhjDc5Qy5nZo4poGwPPWcnznPUmpjjpMsZUa5xiAY1vUsxNbNufSxQ/qr0hd4@l7k4IzG2/EEgv5KHd7WqWdSNS6pveRKJJhIktFvxb96PqJni7GAfNSQjx9ZrtabLR2@2fUf)

```
n->{            // Method with integer parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0,      //  Result-count
      s;        //  Digit-sum
  for(;n>9      //  Loop as long as `n` contains more than 1 digit
      ;         //    After every iteration:
      n=s,      //     Replace the `n` with the sum of digits 
      r++)      //     and increase the result-count
    for(s=0;    //   Reset the sum to 0
        n>0;    //    Inner loop (2) as long as n is larger than 0
        n/=10)  //     Divide n by 10 every iteration
      s+=n%10;  //    And increase the sum with the trailing digit
                //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;     //  Return the result-count
}               // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lua 125

```
function r(n,c,t,m)n=tostring(n)t,c=0,c or 0;for m=1,#n do t=t+n:sub(m,m)end return #n==1 and(print(c)or true)or r(t, c+1)end
```

you call it simply using r({yourNumber})

Comment: why the 3rd and 4th parameters?

Comment: `print(c)or true` to `not print(c)`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
t:"tFYAs]v9>s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RKqcQt0rE4tszSrvj/f0sgAAA)

#### Explanation

```
t        % Implicit input. Duplicate
:"       % Do the following that many times
  t      %   Duplicate
  FYA    %   Convert to base 10: array of decimal digits
  s      %   Sum of array
]        % End
v        % Concatenate stack vertically
9>       % Greater than 9? element-wise
s        % Sum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

31 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$_=eval,$\++while 1<s/./+$&/g}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAv@q8TbppYl5uioxGhrl2dk5qQqGNoU6@vpa6uo6afXVv//b2gEAA)

Short explanations:
`s/./+$&/g` adds a `+` before each digit and returns the number of digits. While this number is greater  than `1`, we set `$_` to the value of the `eval`uation of this string, and increment the number of set (`$\++`). At the end, `$\` is implicitly printed thanks to `-p` and `}{`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

```php
for(;9<$a=&$argn;$a=array_sum(str_split($a)))$p++;echo+$p;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkCQRK1v/T8os0rC1tVBJt1cAS1kBWYlFRYmV8cWmuRnFJUXxxQU5miYZKoqampkqBtrZ1anJGvrZKgfX//1/z8nWTE5MzUgE)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4, 89 bytes

```
func p(i:Int)->Int{return"\(i)".count==1 ?i :p(i:"\(i)".map{Int("\($0)")!}.reduce(0,+))}
```

Swift 4 is still in beta, so you can't run it online. If you have Xcode 9 Beta, it will work.

Un-golfed:

```
func p(i: Int) -> Int {
    return "\(i)".count==1 ? i : p(i: "\(i)".map{Int("\($0)")!}.reduce(0,+))
}
```

Here we check to see how many digits are in the number. If it is only one, we return the number. If not, we turn it into a string, change each character back into an int, get the total sum of all the digits, and run that back through the original function.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 88 bytes

```
#(loop[v(str %)i 0](if(=(count v)1)i(recur(str(apply +(for[c v](-(int c)48))))(inc i))))
```

Oddly long...

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 27 bytes

```
{⍵≤9:0⋄1+∇+/⍵⊤⍨10⍴⍨⌈10⍟1+⍵}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>82</s> 80 bytes

```lua
x=~~...c=0while x>9 do
c=c+1z=0while x>0 do
z=z+x%10x=x//10
end
x=z
end
print(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/wrauTk9PL9nWoDwjMydVocLOUiElnyvZNlnbsAohaAASrLKt0q5QNTSosK3Q1zc04ErNS@GqsK0C0wVFmXklGsma////twQCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 28 bytes

```
V0R1>[dl2-?<1+M&+vm1+R>:v_|]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/zCDI0C46JcdI197GUNtXTbss11A7yM6qLL4m9v///4aWlgA)

### Explanation

```
V0R1>[dl2-?<1+M&+vm1+R>:v_|]  Implicit input of commandline args
V0R                           Create stack2, push 0, return to stack1
   1>                         Push 1 to bottom of stack1
     [.....................]  While loop, will run while bottom item on stack1 is not 0
      d                       Split top of stack into digits
       l2-?                   If length of stack <= 2..
           <1+                ..Move BoS to stop and increment
              M               ..Move item to stack2
               &+             ..Sum entire stack
                 vm           ..Move item back from stack2
                   1+         ..Increment top item on stack2
                     R>       ..Return to stack1 and move ToS to bottom
                       :      Else
                        v_    ..Switch to stack2 and print last item
                          |   Endif
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 26 bytes

```
1`\d.
#$&
\d
$*
}`1+
$.&
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fMCEmRY9LWUWNKyaFS0WLqzbBUJtLRU@NS/n/f0sgAAA) Explanation: The first stage counts the persistence: if there are at least two digits, the persistence (represented here by `#` signs) is incremented. The second stage converts each digit individually to unary, effectively adding them, while the third stage converts back to decimal, looping until a single digit is obtained. It then remains to count the `#` signs.