# Multiplicative persistence

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, repeated-transformation

### Multiplicative Persistence

1. Multiply all the digits in a number
2. Repeat until you have a single digit left

As explained by *Numberphile*:

- [*Numberphile* "What's special about 277777788888899?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wim9WJeDTHQ)
- [*Numberphile* "Multiplicative Persistence (extra footage)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4mrC39sEOQ)

#### Example

1. 277777788888899 → 2x7x7x7x7x7x7x8x8x8x8x8x8x9x9 = 4996238671872
2. 4996238671872 → 4x9x9x6x2x3x8x6x7x1x8x7x2 = 438939648
3. 438939648 → 4x3x8x9x3x9x6x4x8 = 4478976
4. 4478976 → 4x4x7x8x9x7x6 = 338688
5. 338688 → 3x3x8x6x8x8 = 27648
6. 27648 → 2x7x6x4x8 = 2688
7. 2688 → 2x6x8x8 = 768
8. 768 → 7x6x8 = 336
9. 336 → 3x3x6 = 54
10. 54 → 5x4 = 20
11. 20 → 2x0 = 0

This is the current record, by the way: the smallest number with the largest number of steps.

### Golf

A program that takes any whole number as input and then outputs the result of each step, starting with the input itself, until we hit a single digit. For 277777788888899 the output should be

```
277777788888899
4996238671872
438939648
4478976
338688
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
```

(Counting the number of steps is left as an exercise to the user).

#### More Examples

From [A003001](https://oeis.org/A003001):

```
25
10
0
```

From A003001 as well:

```
68889
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
```

From the *Numberphile* video, showing that the single digit doesn't have to be 0:

```
327
42
8
```

---

*So there has been [a question about Additive Persistence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1775/14150), but this is Multiplicative Persistence. Also, that question asks for the number of steps as output, while I'm interested in seeing the intermediate results.*

Comment: Bonus: find a new record: smallest number with the largest number of steps. Caveat: conjecture has it that 11 is the largest possible.

Comment: You probably should include a few more tests cases that do not end with \$0\$.

Comment: Came to make this post, found it already existing, gg

Comment: is a single digit valid input?

Comment: @dzaima yes, but it should only print that number and then stop.

Comment: In the Numberphile video, Matt Parker states that searches have been done to several hundred digits.

Comment: @Arnauld I've added some more examples.

Comment: For languages with type size limits, do we have to use the fancy bignum types or just fit the largest example case (277777788888899)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
DP$Ƭ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98lQOXYmv///xuZg4EFGFhaAgA)

#### Explanation

```
D    | convert to decimal digits
 P   | take the product
  $  | previous two links as a monad
   Ƭ | loop until no change, collecting all intermediate results
```

As a bonus, here's a [TIO](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//RFAkxqxM4oCZ/3LFk8SLQDIsMyw0LDYsNyw4LDnhuIxGw4c7JOKCrDHhu4skw5DhuYD//zH/MTU) which will find the numbers with the largest number of steps for a given range of numbers of digits. It scales well even on TIO.

Answer (score 15):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84), <s>30</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @SolomonUcko!*

```
While Ans>9:Disp Ans:prod(int(10fPart(Ans10^(seq(-X-1,X,0,log(Ans:End:Ans
```

Input is in `Ans`.
Output is displayed as the challenge requests.  The trailing `Ans` is needed to print the last step.

I will admit, I did not think of this formula myself, rather I found it [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/sum-of-digits) and modified it to better fit the challenge.

**EDIT:**  Upon rereading the challenge, I realized that the program must terminate if the product is one digit.  Hence, **2 bytes** were to be added to account for this.

**Example:**

```
24456756
        24456756
prgmCDGF8
        24456756
          201600
               0
11112
           11112
prgmCDGF8
           11112
               2
```

**Explanation:**

```
While Ans>9               ;loop until the product is one digit
Disp Ans                  ;display the current product
prod(                     ;get the product of...
 int(                     ; the integer part of...
  10fPart(                ; ten times the fractional part of...
  Ans                     ; each element in the following list times the
                          ;  current product
  10^(                    ; multiplied by the list generated by using each
                          ;  element of the following list as an exponent
                          ;  for 10^n
   seq(-X-1),X,0,log(Ans  ; generate a list of exponents from -1 to -L where
                          ;  L = the length of the current product
End
Ans                       ;leave the final product in "Ans" and implicitly
                          ; print it
```

**Visual Model:**
`Ans` starts off as `125673`.
This model only covers the logic behind multiplying the digits; everything else is easier to understand.

```
seq(-X-1,X,0,log(Ans  =>  seq(-X-1,X,0,5.0992
   {-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6}
10^(...
   {.1 .01 .001 1E-4 1E-5 1E-6}
Ans...
   {12567.3 1256.73 125.673 12.5673 1.25673 .125673}
fPart(...
   {.3 .73 .673 .5673 .25673 .125673}
10...
   {3 7.3 6.73 5.673 2.5673 1.25673}
int(...
   {3 7 6 5 2 1}
   (the digits of the number, reversed)
prod(...
   1260
   (process is repeated again)

seq(-X-1,X,0,log(Ans  =>  seq(-X-1,X,0,3.1004
   {-1 -2 -3 -4}
10^(...
   {.1 .01 .001 1E-4}
Ans...
   {126 12.6 1.26 .126}
fPart(...
   {0 .6 .26 .126}
10...
   {0 6 2.6 1.26}
int(...
   {0 6 2 1}
prod(...
   0
   (product is less than 10.  loop ends)
```

---

**Notes:**

TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does *not* equal byte count.

`10^(` is [this one-byte token](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/ten-exponent).

This program will not provide the correct sequence of products with integers greater than 14 digits long due to the limitations of decimal precision on the TI calculators.

Comment: Can you save a byte by moving `10^(` outside `seq(` and omitting the closing parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, I believe so!

Answer (score 11):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 9 bytes

```
{*/.'$x}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpLX09dpaI25n@agpE5GFiAgaXlfwA)

`{` `}\` keep applying the function in curly braces until the sequence converges

`$x` format the argument as a string (list of characters)

`.'` evaluate each (other dialects of k require a colon, `.:'`)

`*/` times over, i.e. product

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```r
n=scan();while(print(n)>9)n=prod(n%/%10^(0:log10(n))%%10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCoAgDADQrxG2U2p0qLBPCcKkBrKJCn3@8vpeVSmdhBu0SCVx8DMqhxYvBty/l3KCUok7MB4rcihVbmAzGWdPsFuWx9lxaAag@kV/)

Since `print` `invisibly` returns its input, we can use `print(n)` inside the `while` loop to simulate a `do-while` loop. This is inspired by one of my [tips for golfing in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157131/67312).

The header helps prevent large numbers from being printed in scientific notation.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcgxCoAwDADAvzgloEtVqEjd3f2A1IoBSUJb8fnRGy@baCXhAiWSJg6uR@NQ4s6A83vRnUAzcQXGZUIOmuWAp55@k/XfCNw2DWI3eDQ32gc "R – Try It Online") (with possibly room for improvement, if you can find a shorter way of converting to character).

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ=SP
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BTb4ID//43MwcACDCwtAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@f/cFNvggP@1h7bZ/482MgcDCzCwtNQxMtUxA7F0jI3MYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ     # Loop until the number no longer changes:
 =    #  Print the number with trailing newline (without popping the number itself)
      #  (which will be the implicit input in the first iteration)
  SP  #  Convert the number to a list of digits, and calculate its product
```

Answer (score 8):

## [dzaima/APL](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
∪{×/⍎¨⍕⍵}⍡≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/Rx2rqg9P13/U23doxaPeqY96t9Y@6l34qHPhf02uR31TgWrSFEzhLHNzczjbyBwMLMDA0vI/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
Most@FixedPointList[Times@@IntegerDigits@#&,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773ze/uMTBLbMiNSUgPzOvxCezuCQ6JDM3tdjBwTOvJDU9tcglMz2zpNhBWU1HOVbtf0ARUJWCvoNCerSRORhYgIGlZez//wA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
0Print@#+#>9&&#0@@Times@@@RealDigits@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yCgKDOvxEFZW9nOUk1N2cDBISQzN7XYwcEhKDUxxyUzPbOk2EFZ7X96tJE5GFiAgaVl7P//AA)

-6 bytes from @att

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lfX68iXt@6ws7Sys41OSM/OiQzN7XYwcEzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6TYoSJW7X96tJE5GFiAgaVl7P//AA) if you don't mind using `Echo`.

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yCgKDOvxEFZW9nOUk1N2cDBISQzN7XYwcEhKDUxxyUzPbOk2EFZ7X96tJE5GFiAgaVl7P//AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 23 bytes

```perl6
{$_,{[*] .comb}…10>*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@79aJV6nOlorVkEvOT83qfZRwzJDAzut2v/WCsWJlQppGkbmYGABBpaWmv8B)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>46</s>  43 bytes

-3 thanks to xnor (chained comparison)

```python
def f(n):print n;n>9>f(eval('*'.join(`n`)))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwEETP7VcsvWQjQWwq6Ebot1QwwYhsQk0Fvz6mET048HZgBnbiK10D65wv1oFDlibOnhPwiUcaHdrn@Y5iI7a34BknnqSU2YUZkn0k8AyoD1XHKiIF/a7QF3RhWL0cPewVEJE0bfNZ6DzHJZlO1Ve/NCypxtA2DtdGfish8t/WGw)**

Comment: You can do `>` in place of `and`.

Comment: @xnor thanks, easy to forget that will work.

Answer (score 6):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```julia
f(n)=n>9?[n;f(prod(digits(n)))]:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//8/TSNP0zbPztI@Os86TaOgKD9FIyUzPbOkGCiuqRlrlfc/N7FAI1PXrqAoM68kJ08jU1MnTcPIHAwswMDSUlPzPwA)

Thanks to H.PWiz for -3 bytes.

Comment: You can use `[n;f(prod(digits(n)))]`

Comment: -4 bytes by using an unary operator (for example `!n=...`)

Answer (score 6):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 29 bytes

```
qqlYp:s/./&*/g
C<C-r>=<C-r>"<BS>
<esc>|@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwJ7LAqlhfT19NSz@dy1nIVkiJg0u6xqGw0KHw/38jczCwAANLSwA)

Comment: Looks like you can change the `l` to a `h` (as in Razetime's answer), to remove the `|`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

Returns an array of integers.

```javascript
f=n=>[n,...n>9?f(eval([...n+''].join`*`)):[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchNCoAgEEDhfRfJ6WcWbcwgO4gISWkUMhMVXd@oXd/uvc3d7pyOdb9q4tmnFHrqtaEKEUmrIQh/uyjMm2WeW9x4pbEYATpjbZqYTo4eIy8iCCklQPZ/jfy0H6UA0gM)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>38</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{p(n)>9&&f[eval n.digits*?*]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vukAjT9POUk0tLTq1LDFHIU8vJTM9s6RYy14rtvZ/WrSRORhYgIGlZex/AA)

1 byte saved by by G B.

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>9</s> 10 bytes

```
h(ôo▒ε*h(→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z9D4/CW/EfTJp3bqpWh8aht0v//hlymXJZchsZchkbGJqZcRuZgYAEGlpb/AQ)

Now it correctly handles inputs that are single digits. Not perfect, but at least it is correct.

### Explanation

```
h(            check length of input number and decrease by 1
  ö       →   while true with pop using the next 6 operators
   p          print with newline
    ▒         split to list of chars/digits
     ε*       reduce list by multiplication
       h(     length of TOS without popping, subtracted by 1 (exits when len(TOS) == 1)
```

Comment: The output for a single digit input should be one copy of the number - clarified in the comments

Comment: @dzaima I'll look into it, and update the answer when it's solved

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>79</s> <s>74</s> 68 bytes

```cs
void f(int a){Print(a);if(a>9)f((a+"").Aggregate(1,(j,k)=>k%48*j));}
```

I try to stay away from recursion in C# due to how long the method declaration is, but in this case it saves compared to a loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LD8zRSFNIzOvRCFRszqgCMjQSNS0zkzTSLSz1EzT0EjUVlLS1HNMTy9KTU8sSdUw1NHI0snWtLXLVjWx0MrS1LSu/Q/WrxeQWFScqhGUmpjik5mXqqEJlPpvYmEEAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>61</s> <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```python
def f(n):print n;n>9and f(reduce(int.__mul__,map(int,`n`)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0/TqqAoM69EIc86z84yMS8FKFaUmlKanKoBFNWLj88tzYmP18lNLADxdRLyEjQ1Nf@naRiZg4EFGFhaanKBTeECShhr/gcA)

<sub>-3 bytes, thanks to Jonathan Allan</sub>

Comment: Doesn't work for inputs that don't end with a 0 on their last iteration, for example 23

Comment: `int.__mul__` is three bytes less than `lambda a,b:a*b`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! I knew there had to be something like that

Comment: Change `f(reduce(int.__mul__,map(int,\`n\`)))` to `f(eval('*'.join(\`n\`)))` to save 13 bytes.

Comment: @mypetlion ...I already did that in another post.

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 54 bytes

```powershell
for($a=$args;$a-gt9){$a;$a=("$a"|% t*y)-join"*"|iex}$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEMl0VYlsSi92FolUTe9xFKzWiURyLTVUFJJVKpRVSjRqtTUzcrPzFPSUqrJTK2oVUn8//@/kTkYWICBpSUA)

---

Iterative method that first writes the input argument, then converts it into a string and pipes it into a character array. This array is joined by a single asterisks, and executed as a command with the invoke expression alias. Since this writes Starting number down to the last number greater than 0, (20, in the given test scenario), I add a final `$a` to the end to output.

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
<?=$n=$argn;while($n>9)echo"
",$n=array_product(str_split($n));
```

Iterative version, call with `php -nF` input from `STDIN`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSep2CrkJaeWlKsERzi4umnaa1gbweUtlXJswVLW5dnZOakaqjk2VlqpiZn5CtxKekA5RKLihIr4wuK8lNKk0s0ikuK4osLcjJLgOo0Na3//zcyBwMLMLC0BAA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>72</del> 71 bytes

```php
function h($n){echo"$n
",($n=array_product(str_split($n)))>9?h($n):$n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MUMjRU8jSrU5Mz8pVU8riUdIBc28SiosTK@IKi/JTS5BKN4pKi@OKCnMwSkEpNTTtLe7AeK5U869r/II1AMxTS0lNLijWCQ1w8/TQVNHUUAjwC4l39faz/G5mDgQUYWFoCAA)

Recursive version, as function.

Input: [277777788888899](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MUMjRU8jSrU5Mz8pVU8riUdIBc28SiosTK@IKi/JTS5BKN4pKi@OKCnMwSkEpNTTtLe7AeK5U869r/II1AMxTS0lNLijWCQ1w8/TQVNHUUAjwC4l39faz/G5mDgQUYWFoCAA)

```php
277777788888899
4996238671872
438939648
4478976
338688
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
```

Input: [23](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MUMjRU8jSrU5Mz8lXydJS4lHSAfNvEoqLEyviCovyU0uQSjeKSovjigpzMEpBSTU07S3uwJiuVPOva/yCdQEMU0tJTS4o1gkNcPP00FTR1FAI8AuJd/X2s/xsZAwA)

```php
23
6
```

Answer (score 5):

## perl 5 (`-n` `-M5.01`), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```
say$_=eval;s/\B/*/g&&redo
```

[25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIl3ja1LDHHulg/xklfSz9dTa0oNSX//38jczCwAANLy3/5BSWZ@XnF/3Xz/uv6muoZGAIA)

[30 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIl3ja1LDHHulhfw14xrkZFU19LP11NrSg1Jf//fyNzMLAAA0vLf/kFJZn5ecX/dfP@6/qa6hkYAgA)

[32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sdJaRclWXUvdWkMl3ja1LDFHycFNSdPOUk2tKDUl//9/I3MwsAADS8t/@QUlmfl5xf91cwrc9PX/6/qa6hkYAgA)

Comment: You should mention that this uses `-lpF//`

Comment: @Grimy i could save 2 bytes without using `-lpF//`, updating

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
filter f{$_
if($_-gt9){("$_"|% t*y)-join'*'|iex|f}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDdasMwDIXv8xTGuDQuCtQ/seXBYG@Si83ZUkLapRnrSPLsmZwtZUwXx9KnI2R0OX/G/voW23ZZ6qYdYs/qUVRZU@eiKl6HIMeci4pPOzYcvmRxOjfd/rCfmnib6nlenvKMUUCu/Rq4RgjA/gMbgtMGnVfoNViDwQRnEaz1GLwDQz1E0D5BnVLvkKiD0oI@wlH@blJAj9oqbagkcfd2Iuov0cbSd0i0BdxgmeZIVAnlxrwnRmID0FqFyS3ZxHZsXB2iAybi7RKfh/jCHhndacV9vH60QwLdVK@IC7raD@ZFfOf3KS4fNj/P5uUb)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
([:*/,.&.":)^:a:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F8j2kpLX0dPTU/JSjPOKtHqvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagpE5GFiAgaUl138A)

Comment: This doesn’t work for very large numbers as it then switches into floating point mode, even putting x on the end doesn’t help                  ([:*/,.&.":)^:a:3777788889999977777777777x
3.77779e24
 3.4448e21
         0
         0

Comment: @RichardDonovan Yes, you're right - thank you for your obsrevation! I don't know how to  fix it.

Comment: @GalenIvanov `([:*&x:/,.&.":)^:a:` fixes it (you also need the x on the input), though I think your existing answer is still legal.

Answer (score 4):

## APL(NARS), 19 chars, 38 bytes

```
{⍵≤9:⍵⋄∇×/⍎¨⍕⍵⊣⎕←⍵}
```

test:

```
   f←{⍵≤9:⍵⋄∇×/⍎¨⍕⍵⊣⎕←⍵}
   f 23     
23
6
   f 27648     
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 45 bytes

```
f n=n:[x|n>9,x<-f$product$read.pure<$>show n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzbPKrqiJs/OUqfCRjdNpaAoP6U0uUSlKDUxRa@gtCjVRsWuOCO/XCEv9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagpE5GFiAgaXlfwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 bytes

Horribly inefficient - don't even *try* to run the first test case!

```
_ì ×}hN â
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI=&code=X%2bwg131oTiDi&input=Nzc3)

```
_ì ×}hN â     :Implicit input of integer U
      N       :Starting with the array of inputs (i.e., [U])
     h        :Do the following U times, pushing the result to N each time
_             :Take the last element in N and pass it through the following function
 ì            :  Convert to digit array
   ×          :  Reduce by multiplication
    }         :End function
        â     :Deduplicate N
              :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 4):

## Chevron, 100 bytes

```
>^__>>^n
->+11?^n<10
>^n
^d<<1
^i<<1
^m<^i>^n
->+4??^m=^__
^d<<^d*^m
^i<<^i+1
->-4
^n<<^d
->-10
><^n
```

This is a fairly new language of my own creation - prototype interpreter, documentation, and example programs can be found at https://github.com/superloach/chevron.

### Explanation:

- `>^__>>^n` - take the input as a NUM, with empty prompt
- `->+11?^n<10` - if the number is under 10 (1 digit), skip to the end
- `>^n` - output the current number
- `^d<<1` - initialise the product to 1
- `^i<<1` - initialise the character index to 1
- `^m<^i>^n` - get i'th character of the number
- `->+4??^m=^__` - jump out of loop if no character is found
- `^d<<^d*^m` - multiply character into product
- `^i<<^i+1` - increment character index
- `->-4` - hop back to continue getting characters
- `^n<<^d` - once loop is done, assign product as new number
- `->-10` - hop all the way to the beginning for the next iteration
- `><^n` - exit, printing the final number

Comment: Welcome. Great first answer!

Comment: @mbomb007 thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 46 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a>9?[a,...f(eval([...a+''].join`*`))]:[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpLDkAwFAXQ5Wh93sBAkGAh1aQXrZCmTxDbL4nZGZwdD6753I67mDBZXwRebIyuQ9ejbwaFnIicsA@8UB@RJYmmnbdgUiOlbhV0nDlc7C15XoUTZVXX8i9jMDK@)

---

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 44 bytes

*If the input can be taken as String*

```javascript
f=a=>a>9?[a,...f(''+eval([...a].join`*`))]:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrdCkAwGAbgy9nm5yvKAYULQe3FaGvtE3L7oxw@9Tg8uJbTHnc@YzY@D7yaGLcWbYeu7gdkRLRJIVLzwMvhEyZybINOtFJTg7hwuNgb8rzLb1ZFKdQ/xqBVfAE)

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, I just edited and added the wrong code. Im still looking for something using only strings instead arrays

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
ẉ?Ḋ|ẹ×↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuTvuHO7pqHu7aeXj6o7YN//8bmYOBBRhYWv4HAA)

#### Explanation

```
ẉ          Write the input followed by a linebreak
 ?Ḋ        If the input is a single digit, then it's over
   |       Otherwise
    ẹ      Split the input into a list of digits
     ×     Multiply them together
      ↰    Recursive call with the result of the multiplication as input
```

Comment: I gave it a try myself. Forgot about the Ḋ. The rest i had the same.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>64</s> 59 bytes

```powershell
for($a="$args";9-lt$a){$a;$a="$(($a|% t*y)-join'*'|iex)"}$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEMl0VZJJbEovVjJ2lI3p0QlUbNaJdEaLKoBlKxRVSjRqtTUzcrPzFPXUq/JTK3QVKpVSfz//7@RORhYgIGlJQA)

Iterative method. Takes input and stores it into `$a`, then enters a `for` loop so long as the length of `$a` is two or more (i.e., it's bigger than `9`). Inside the loop we output `$a` and then recalculate it by converting it `t`oCharArra`y`, `join`ing it together with `*`, and then `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`). Once we're out of the loop, we have a single digit left to print, so we place `$a` onto the pipeline again.

*-5 bytes thanks to KGlasier.*

Comment: You could use the comparison `9-lt$a` instead of `$a.length-1` to save 5 bytes. And if you didn't go string based the whole time you could cut off a decent chunk. Check out [my powershell attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181976/83875) if you want!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
θＷ⊖Ｌθ«≔ＩΠθθ⸿θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRKNQ05qrPCMzJ1VBwyU1uSg1NzWvJDVFwyc1L70kAyirqalQzcXpWFycmZ6n4ZxYXKIRUJSfUpoM0qmpowDSzgkxSSmmSAnBA0nU/v9vZA4GFmBgaflftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
θ
```

Print the input for the first time.

```
Ｗ⊖Ｌθ«
```

Repeat while the length of the input is not 1.

```
≔ＩΠθθ
```

Replace the input with its digital product cast to string.

```
⸿θ
```

Print the input on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 24 bytes

```
.+~(\`

.
$&$*
^
.+¶$$.(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@7TiMmgYtLj0tFTUWLK45LT/vQNhUVPY3//43MwcACDCwtAQ) Explanation:

```
.+~(\`
```

Print the current value on its own line at the start of every loop until it stops changing and don't print the unchanged value twice. Evaluate the current value at the end of each loop.

```
.
$&$*
```

Add a `*` after each digit.

```
^
.+¶$$.(
```

Finish turning the input into an expression that evaluates to the digital product.

Just for the record, Retina can do this in one line (25 bytes):

```
.+"¶"<~[".+¶$.("|'*]'*L`.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>112</s> 106 bytes

*"Lossy conversion"* thanks Java for the extra ~15 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen
Obligatory stream abuse answer

```
n->{for(long t=10;t>9;n=(n+"").chars().mapToLong(i->i).reduce(1,(x,y)->x*(y-48)))System.out.println(t=n);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jZC/bsMgEIf3PMUpE7QBJemfxLLsJ0izpFvVgWLskthnC3AUK/Kzu5h47OAbToL74PfBWVwFO2eXQZbCWvgQGu8LAI1OmVxIBcdxCXCtdQY5KWssAGns9/qFb9YJpyUcASGBAVl6z2vzoFyyWccujWJMCD4vl5TLX2EsobwSzWd98AzRLNWUG5W1UpHNitxWHWXp7Yl07HVPKT111qmK163jjfFOJRKX@Ph@GA2a9qf04ZNDMKy8Pzk5zxZf3yBMYenDH3lOtrtQ@1BRdAjPAPgnZJqEQ2@zsPfxylnky3Y3i4umX@6HPw)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you only need to support `int`

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance then it fails for `277777788888899` since `4996238671872` is too large for an int

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZC/bsMgEIf3PMUpE7QBJemfxLLsJ0izpFvVgWLskthnC3AUK/Kzu5h47OAbToL74PfBWVwFO2eXQZbCWvgQGu8LAI1OmVxIBcdxCXCtdQY5KWssAGns9/qFb9YJpyUcASGBAVl6z2vzoFyyWccujWJMCD4vl5TLX2EsobwSzWd98AzRLNWUG5W1UpHNitxWHWXp7Yl07HVPKT111qmK163jjfFOJRKX@Ph@GA2a9qf04ZNDMKy8Pzk5zxZf3yBMYenDH3lOtrtQ@1BRdAjPAPgnZJqEQ2@zsPfxylnky3Y3i4umX@6HPw) by making it non-recursive.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 58 bytes

```c
f(n,t){for(;n=printf("%d\n",t=n)>2;)for(;n*=t%10,t/=10;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@nRLM6Lb9IwzrPtqAoM68kTUNJNSUmT0mnxDZP087IWhMiqWVbompooFOib2toYK1pXfs/NzEzT0OzmitNw8TE3MLS3EzTmqv2PwA)

Iterative approach turns out to be 1 byte shorter.

```c
f(n,t){
    for(;n=printf("%d\n",t=n)   //print and update current number
            >2;)                //until only one digit is printed
        for(;n*=t%10,t/=10;);   //n*= product of digits of t (step)
}
```

---

### [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> 59 bytes (recursive)

```c
f(n){printf("%d\n",n)>2&&f(p(n));}p(n){n=n?n%10*p(n/10):1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zuqAoM68kTUNJNSUmT0knT9POSE0tTaMAKKVpXQuiqvNs8@zzVA0NtIA8fUMDTStD69r/uYmZeRqa1VxpGiYm5haW5maa1ly1/wE)

<s>Recursion seems to be shorter than iteration for both print and step...</s>

Answer (score 3):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>43 30</s></sup> 29 bytes

```
qqhYp:s/./*&/g
x0C<C-r>=<C-r>"
<esc>@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwI7LAqlhfT19LTT@dq8LA2cZZt8jOFkwqcdmkFifbORQWOhT@/29kDgYWYGBp@V@3DAA)

-13 bytes from DJMcMayhem. [Go upvote their answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223102/80214)

-1 byte from user41805.

Takes advantage of the fact that this only stops on single digit numbers.

### Explanation

```
qqhYp:s/./*&/g
qq                  create a macro @q:
  l                  move one char right
                     this is the break condition, since you cant 
                     move to the right from a single digit
   Yp                duplicate the current line
     :s/./*&/g       add "*" before each digit

x0C<C-r>=<C-r>"     
x                    delete first char
 0C                  cut the current line and store in " register
   <C-r>=            evaluate the following string:
         <C-r>"      the value in " register
                     and paste in current line
 
@qq@q
@q                   recursively call macro
  q                 close macro
   @q               call macro q
```

Comment: You can use `*&` instead to save some bytes

Answer (score 2):

**Swift, 115 bytes**

```
func m(a:Int){
print("\(a)")
var b=1,c=a
while c>0{
b*=c%10
c/=10}
b>9 ? m(a:b):print("\(b)")}
m(a:277777788888899)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFXI9HKM69Es5qroCgzr0RDKUYjUVNJk6sssUghydZQJ9k2kas8IzMnVSHZzqCaK0nLNlnV0IArWd/W0KCWK8nOUsEebEaSphXcgCSgAbVcIFEjczCwAANLS83//wE)

Comment: I think you can move the call to `m` into the Footer portion of TIO, leaving this answer as [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFXI9HKM69Es5qroCgzr0RDKUYjUVNJk6sssUghydZQJ9k2kas8IzMnVSHZzqCaK0nLNlnV0IArWd/W0KCWK8nOUsEebEaSphXcgCSgAbX/QaJG5mBgAQaWlpr/AQ)

Comment: Also, [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFXI9HKM69Es7qgKDOvRCNRk6sssUghydZQJ9k2kas8IzMnVSHZzqA6Scs2WdXQgCtZ39bQoJYryc5SwR6kN0nTCqIzSbP2P0jAyBwMLMDA0lLzPwA) by removing some whitespace/formatting redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

## [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com/), <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```lisp
(de f(x)(if(> 10 x)(list x)(cons x(f(apply *(mapcar format(chop x)))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYoxDoAgEAS/cuVipTZq418QuUiCcEEKfT2ixmlmk1lxJnp3SClYLTFOBceYqWupzlryYxPDQScYWsRf1GDXYnQijmnXGWaLUm8f5Y@SXMg@EJj64WV8mSalsFxWlRs)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 15 bytes

I got some help from [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) on this one.

```
@pUÌì × Ì>9}f U
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QHBVzOwg1yDMPjl9ZiBV&input=WzI3Nzc3Nzc4ODg4ODg5OV0KCi1S)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▒σ╛g
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b1e5be67&i=277777788888899&a=1)

Unpacked, it's pretty simple.

```
gu  use the rest of the program to generate values until a duplicate is encountered
    output implicitly
E:* calculate product of digits
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 23 bytes

```perl6
{$_,{[*] .comb}...10>*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@79aJV6nOlorVkEvOT83qVZPT8/QwE6r9r81V1p@kYKNkTkYWICBpaWCkamCGYilYGxkbqega6egkqdQzcVZnFipoARkAgWq04BitUpctf8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
U¡oΠd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/TQwvxzC1L@//9vZA4GFmBgaQkA)

### Explanation

```
U¡oΠd
 ¡    iterate infinitely, collecting results of each iteration
  o   combination of 2 functions
    d get digits
   Π  multiply all of them
U     cut at first duplicate value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe, quickly superseded by -4 bytes (a different way) thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
n=scan();while(print(n)>9)n=prod(utf8ToInt(c(n,""))-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEADAv3jahbpYkBJ2794HwoyE2F3U6PkWznFSZSmRKUP2UQI5PWAll/1OgPN7xTuApEgFCBeL5CTxAU85zcbrvx6oUwqxHw1WPTWmsbZ@)

A different method to [Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181968/95126) for the same number of bytes, here as a full recursive function instead of the (often-shorter) approach of taking input from the console using `scan`.

Comment: This (and mine) can be shortened by using `0:log10(x)` instead of the `nchar` thing, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

## POSIX Shell + Utilities, 59 bytes

```sh
echo $1
[ ${#1} = 1 ]||$0 $(echo $1|fold -w1|paste -sd*|bc)
```

```
$ cat cg; echo; wc -c cg
echo $1
[ ${#1} = 1 ]||$0 $(echo $1|fold -w1|paste -sd*|bc)
59 cg
$ ./cg 277777788888899
277777788888899
4996238671872
438939648
4478976
338688
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
$ ./cg 25
25
10
0
$ ./cg 327
327
42
8
$ ./cg 68889
68889
27648
2688
768
336
54
20
0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 87 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(n int){Println(n)
s:=1
if n<10{return}
for;n>0;n/=10{s*=n%10}
f(s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjfDM3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jTyFDLzSjSrA4qAVE6eRp4mV7GVrSFXZppCno2hQXVRaklpUV4tV1p-kXWenYF1nr4tULRYyzZP1dAAKKxRrFkLMX4P2ECQdRqaCtVAGRNjC0tjSzMTC00uqJIFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
,[1svy*}Ð,gΘ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fJ9qwuKxSq/bwBJ30czOU//83s7CwsAQA)

Explanation:

```
,            //Print input
[            //Begin infinite loop
    1s       //Set 1 to the item before the input in the stack
    v        //Loop over the input
        y*   //Add the current character to the stack and multiply
    }        //End loop
    Ð        //Triplicate result
    ,        //Print result
    gΘ       //Check if length == 1
#            //If so, end
```

Leaving out the two prints can save two bytes while still outputting the result, thanks to implicit output. Without that restriction this would be 11.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## java 8, <s>105</s> 104 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Benjamin Urquhart, replacing `'0'` with `48`

```
i->{String s="";for(;(s+=i+"\n")!=""&i>9;){long m=1;for(byte c:(""+i).getBytes())m*=c-48;i=m;}return s;}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##jY87T8MwFIX3/oqLB2QTYomHRINxBgamMnWEDm6aRA5@yXYqRVF@ezBpkBg5snTt4@9I53biLHLratOdvmapnfURuuTRPkpFm95UUVpD39YL27j@qGQFlRIhwLuQBsYNJK1@iCKmcbbyBDr9YthHL037cQDh2wBkxX@0H0KsNbV9pC4xUSW6ocI5NWC4f1q0XVQUu5Qk7J/Rhz/0tFkr/a7wsrOmvb20KqHhs8zL8fKEwBFijfWY4ZBxmaFPg8hVMq9lWTAyqhQFze8W5jjEGqpnjFAmCW3r@JqMgAnRN7zKH7dMcs0mX8feGwhsmtP5Bg)

Comment: -1 byte by replacing `'0'` with 48

Comment: With java 10 you could save a few bytes by writing `var` instead of `String` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>79</s> 72 bytes

```
: f ( x -- ) [ 10 >base [ 48 - ] map product dup dup . 9 > ] loop drop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NCsIwEITvPsUc9dCiItgf6FV6sAjiSURiusVgbGKyEX36GDuwH8POMjsIycbF07HtdhUe5EbSeAq@T8itcJ4cPL0CjZI8rCPmr3VqZNSztquwD5qV1UoKVm@6Hsh55fl/HSsMmOODLMMCZ6yWaG7CU7KbAhku6YdNjaYPktEHO02OEk3KtDFp4RLquN5OKiaVJYb4Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 66 bytes

```
=p(n)
{n}{n<10:->->}
~temp v=1
-(a)~v=v*n%10
~n=n/10
{n:->a}->p(v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/q9rV6BhbGSuqWvHFaMAQiABE2MLS2NLMxMLVGFjIPe/bYFGniZXdV5tdZ6NoYGVrp2uXS1XXUlqboFCma0hl65GomZdmW2ZVp6qoQFXXZ5tnj6Qrs4DKkysBRlSpvn/PwA)

## Explanation

```
=p(n)       // entry point - a stitch called p, with one parameter.
{n}         // print the value of n
{n<10:->->} // if n is a single digit, divert to wherever we entered from
~temp v=1   // declate a variable v, where we keep track of the product, and set it to 1
-(a)        // a labeled gather - we can jump here later
~v=v*n%10   // multiply v by (n mod 10) - the last digit in n
~n=n/10     // divide n by 10 - removing the last digit
{n:->a}     // if n is nonzero, go back to a
->p(v)      // if we reach this, divert to the top, this time with n set to the value of v
```

Doesn't feel very golfed, but I have no idea how you'd improve it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
b=input()
while 1:
 a=str(b);print a;b=1
 if len(a)<2:break
 for d in list(a):b*=int(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoMgEEbhPaf4l@BONq0oh2EixknJSHCaxtNT47d9yauX7of43imy1K9aZ347l4wxGKR4arPk5tpYFGmmOBrwhpLFJrf4QC2nj8F2NKxgQeFT7xJouHdqV9e7fz3ej2n6Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 100 bytes

```
	P =INPUT
O	OUTPUT =N =P	:(S)
S	P =GT(N,9) 1	:F(END)
D	N LEN(1) . D REM . N	:F(O)
	P =P * D	:(D)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNAwdbTLyA0hMuf0z80BMhQsPVTsA3gtNII1uQKBkm7h2j46VhqKhhyWrlpuPq5aHK5cPop@Lj6aRhqKugpuCgEufoCaT@QtL8mF0hLgIKWggvQCKBaoIb//43MwcACDCwtAQ)

A nice round 100 bytes!

```
	P =INPUT			;* Store input to P
O	OUTPUT =N =P	:(S)		;* print P and set N to P
S	P =GT(N,9) 1	:F(END)		;* if N > 9, set P (the digit product) to 1
D	N LEN(1) . D REM . N	:F(O)	;* take the first digit of N as D and set remaining digits to N
					;* if N is an empty string, goto label O
	P =P * D	:(D)		;* calculate the digit product, then return to D
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>138</s> 115 bytes

```c
long atol(char*);main(c,v)char**v;{long z=1,n=atol(v[1]);for(;printf("%ld\n",n),n>9;n=z,z=1)for(;z*=n%10,n/=10;);}
```

Pass the number as a first command line argument.

Thanks to attinat for help with saving some bytes.

Ungolfed and prettyified:

```c
long atol(char *);
main(c, v) char **v; {
    long z = 1,n = atol(v[1]);
    for(; printf("%ld\n", n), n > 9; n = z, z = 1)
        for(; z *= n % 10, n /= 10;);
}
```

Comment: [`for`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168932/81203) can save you quite a few bytes.

Comment: Suggest `int**v` instead of `char**v`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
j.u*FsM`N
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.u%2aFsM%60N&input=277777788888899&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=277777788888899%0A25%0A68889%0A327&debug=0)

If we're allowed to output as an array, the `j` at the start is unnecessary, giving 8 bytes.

Comment: You can also omit the `N` at the end, since Pyth implicitly adds lambda variables at the end of a program if needed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 107 bytes

```
(define(f n)(if(> 10 n)(list n)(cons n(f(apply *(map(λ(x)(-(char->integer x)48))(string->list(~v n))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCsIwFET3nuKDm/lCQUWw3fQi4iK0Sf0Yf0MSpN14Me/glWpbfZuZWcxMNM3d5mnrjXYUfwGtdaIWjpQhDjUd9ov1kvKiTa@JFA4mBD/SDg8T8HljYBRobiYWtWi2nY008KlkRspRtCvqZQGv5zzyZ4LrI@EiNL8dzyvlSlXxlTdEhFZS8Gb0SjIXvg)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>192 191</s> 180 bytes

```cs
using C=System.Console;class A{static void Main(string[] a){long i,k;var b=a[0];for(C.WriteLine(b);(k=b.Length)>1;C.WriteLine(b=i.ToString())){i=1;for(int j=0;j<k;)i*=b[j++]-48;}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBC4IwGIDhv7LjljW0goK1ILzayaCDeNjWsk9tg20JIf72Jd46vzyv8htlnY7x48E0KOfl1wf9prk13vaaqV54jy6jDyKAQoOFB7oKMNgHN4OqRoKMvZ0prDs2CIckF1Vas6d1OKd3B0EXYDSWhOGOS1po04QXOWfsr3KgN1suT0wIGYFnywJMQC1PWXvqGIEVl1WbJPVmf2TTNMUYd9vDDw)

Pretty much just naive looping.  I feel like that's a bit of a silly way to do it but here we are.  Had a weird issue early on where the input didn't match the output, because it was overflowing an `int`, so here we are with `long`s.  I could upgrade it to `BigInteger` if I needed to, though that would cost a few bytes.

I swear I always end up with off by ones when I do loops here, and it annoys me to no end.

Ungolfed-ish version:

```cs
using C=System.Console;
class A{
    static void Main(string[] a){
        long i,k;
        var b=a[0];
        for(C.WriteLine(b);(k=b.Length)>1;C.WriteLine(b=i.ToString())){
            i=1;
            for(int j=0;j<k;)i*=b[j++]-48;
        }
    }
}
```

## Works for all integers less than int.MAX_VALUE digits long, [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 204 bytes

```cs
using C=System.Console;class A{static void Main(string[] a){System.Numerics.BigInteger i;int j,k;var b=a[0];for(C.WriteLine(b);(k=b.Length)>1;C.WriteLine(b=i.ToString())){i=1;for(j=0;j<k;)i*=b[j++]-48;}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1NawIxFAD/So6JH0FbwcJrhHZPBetFwcOyh2z6XN@uJpAXBVn2t0cRLz0PM@N46kLEnC9MvhGF2d444VkXwXM4IbiTZRZfPSebyIlroD/xa8lLTvEhlJWwqn85m8sZIznW39T8@IQNRkFAPol20sHVRlEbW84qOIQoC72PlHBNHmWtQHam1mv0TTqq1Rz@UUN6F7bPn1RK9WTmz0RrZtB@dqBoZOqyHY@r6eIDhmHIOb@/Le8)

Comment: Saved 1 byte - moved C.WriteLine(b) into loop opening as well as iterator

Comment: Saved 11 bytes with assorted rearrangements.

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
{If[_>9,_'$@Prod@List@_,_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBlq/C/2jMtOt7OUideXcUhoCg/xcEns7jEIV4nPrb2v19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkK0kTkYWICBpaWOghmI1lEwNjLXUTAyjY39DwA)

Oddly enough, the recursive approach, rather than a tacit approach, seems to be shortest. (There is a bug in `NestListWhile` involving currying, but even with the bugfix it'd be 3 bytes longer.)

### Explanation

```
{
    If[ _ > 9 ,
        ?? if this is true, return a list
        [
            ?? with the current number
            _,
            ?? followed by this function called on the digital product
            ...$[ Prod[Digits[_]] ]
        ],
        ?? otherwise, return _
        _
    ]
}
```

### Alternative

**32 bytes:** `NestListWhile<~Prod@List,{_>9}~>`

Answer (score 1):

### c++, lambda function, 72 bytes

```
[](auto n){while(cout<<n<<endl&&n>9){auto t=n;for(n=1;n*=t%10,t/=10;);}}
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoMwEEDRtXOKQKkkpaXaTStJvEjpIsRoAzoRM6EL8ewp5K3@4tt1vU3W5pNHO6fBMeVDpM2ZpQdI0ePE0CwursY6FmmQAB6JLcYjF7BDZRIFNur8/vCSKPbf18@O25BIKVTK4TDXNfad2MtBGuUYNo66lXjRdG6bK91120ghjyNLqKAa@eNZvIquExIOyH8)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 73 bytes

```
#(loop[i %](prn i)(if(> i 9)(recur(apply *(for[c(str i)](-(int c)48))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 83 bytes

```scala
def^(n:Long):Long={println(n);if(n>9)^((n+"").map(x=>(x-48).toLong).product)else n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCsMgEEDRfU8hWc1Q6iIUGlsS6D5nEKxOSoodJVoQQs5uwbf4u5@s8aaG14dsFlZQycQuiWeMYq@OFg18nwO/sXXc47Zy9gyMj3UBnhRqAD53HcqviVDGCcrlOqDMoW0ybsH9bEbyiQQfVUN/a4ZGKY@no9Y/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
&;1\v>#;:.:9`!#@_;
>$$  ^
^#::< '*%ap25/a_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X83aMKbMTtnaSs/KMkFR2SHemstORUVBIY4rTtnKykZBXUs1scDIVD8x/v9/I3MwsAADS0sA)

The first line takes input, prints the values and runs until a value `<=9` is reached. The third line computes the product of digits of an integer ([26 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/31CtjMvKyibdwFhLNbHAwFg/MV5F2VpFz8H6/38jUzMA) on its own).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
W9<Pa$*:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/3NImIFFFyyrx////RuZgYAEGlpYA)

#### Explanation

```
           a is command-line argument (implicit)
W          While...
   Pa      (print a's value)
 9<        ... a is greater than 9, i.e. more than one digit:
     $      Fold
        a   (the digits of) a
      *     on multiplication
       :    and assign back to a
```

Printing `a` in the loop header lets us output its value both before the loop and when the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Jo King

```
:nao:a),1}\~
1:,a}*{%a:/!?:-%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yovMd8qUVPHsDamjsvQSiexVqtaNdFKX9HeSlf1////umVG5mBgAQaWlgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 40 bytes

```factor
[ [ .s >dec 48 v-n Π dup 9 > ] loop . ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BasMwEEX3PsXPvpZLG2jtgCGbFkPJJnQVgnGksR0qS2I0TuhteqJeyU3sTTfDDP/z3rSNFs/T577avRcITCLfgc9OMDTSz0OFhiPxsl/o3o/LMbqz9obwRezIYoNqV6Dztk22H9V2X6A0pOHG4URcRrlhO2CFt9mJR5XnSFNEIvQiIRZZZryOqp3zO1l57jLtnZCT7OrZpHXdSV3fsA//XlO9DDZJnp9epgMOUHERr19xSR1@f2DGgBwljrDeBygcJ91YO/0B)

- `[ ... dup 9 > ] loop` loop while top of stack is greater than nine
- `.s` print stack non-destructively
- `>dec` convert number to string
- `48 v-n` convert string to list of digits
- `Π` product of a list of numbers
- `.` print the leftover number (which will be the final output)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
def f(n):print(n);n>9>f(eval('*'.join(str(n))))
```

First Python 3 answer here.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3hCgIhEIR/11Ms90cNiU6D0uDeJUjJiFW8vaCnt80gqA9md5mBnfKka0bb2iVEiBKVLzUh8XHCyU1Rhsf5LsVGbG85oZypcsS0mCtQmAkSgjSHzrHjnIZxxxpZhmXfm4exew3OOeXXq0/LkLAs5AfdX6mvnRfqPjtR/kRCqPbX9gI)

Answer (score 1):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 38 bytes

```
Product Minus 48 Show compose3 fixiter
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack): pass the input number as a command-line argument and enter the program on stdin.

#### Explanation

The `fixiter` modifier iterates a function until it reaches a fixed value, returning the full list of intermediate values. This is exactly what we want; there is a slight complication because the builtin `ToBase` function, which returns a list of digits, converts zero to an empty list rather than a list containing `0`. So instead, we convert the number to a string and then convert each character to the corresponding digit.

```
                      compose3          Compose these three functions:
                 Show                     Convert number to string
        Minus 48                          Subtract 48 from each character
Product                                   Take the product of the character codes
                               fixiter  Iterate that function, stopping when a fixed point
                                        is reached, and return a list of intermediate values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 2 bytes

```
ᵘΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLhtZjOoCIsIiIsIjI3Nzc3Nzc4ODg4ODg5OSIsIjMuMS4wIl0=)

2 bytes with a new modifier. Come try Vyxal 3!

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `j`, 3 bytes

```
⁽Π↔
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%81%BD%CE%A0%E2%86%94&inputs=277777788888899&header=&footer=)

Very nice little 3 byter here. Uses the same method as the 05ab1e answer.

### Explained

```
⁽Π↔
⁽Π  # lambda x: product(x) // treats numbers as a list of digits
 ↔ # repeat the above function until the result doesn't change, collecting intermediate results.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
Đ`ҎĐłŕ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISES31HJhxtOjr1/38jczCwAANLSwA)

```
Đ         Implicit input; duplicate top of stack
 `  ł     do while top of stack is not 0 (consumes top of stack when checking)
  Ҏ       digit product of top of stack
   Đ      duplicate top of stack
     ŕ    remove top of stack (duplicate 0); implicit print
```

Comment: Fails for input `327` (since it does not necessarily end with 0).

Answer (score 0):

it's not efficient but gets the job done

```
echo 777777777777777777777777777777777779999999999999999999933333333333  |


gawk -M 'function __(_){return _*_==_?+$_:$_*__(--_)}($_=__(NF*=!/0/))_' FS=
```

> ```
> 815859530632739726716133814001433680647636177446909421
> ```