# Number chopping: Split a number into its digits

Tags: code-golf, string, number

## Number Splitting

### Instructions

Oh no, my numbers have stuck together! Luckily, we can split them apart with code.

Your code should be a function that takes an integer input from stdin or as an argument. You must split the number into single digits, keeping the order and possible duplicates of these digits. The output should be an array and it may be returned from the function or from stdout. Other forms of output may be discussed. The array elements may be a string or number.

### Examples

```
345 -> [3, 4, 5]
12218 -> [1, 2, 2, 1, 8]
```

### Scoring

This is code golf, so shortest code wins.

Comment: As you don't have an a negative number in the examples, will the input always be zero or greater?

Comment: Please, put your questions in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before posting them. Your submission is bascially something like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181958/multiplicative-persistence), but with lesser steps. Please check for similiar questions before posting, as well.

Comment: Firstly, it is generally discouraged to accept answers here as that discourages further answers. Secondly, even if you decided to accept an answer, you should at least wait for several weeks, which is significantly longer than 1 hour. Thirdly, the JS answer is not the shortest, why accepting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript, 12 bytes

-3 bytes if we can take input as a string.

```javascript
n=>[...n+""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT08vT1tJKfZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaxiamm5n8A)

Comment: Absolutely destroyed me. Congratulations.

Comment: Firstly, it is generally discouraged to accept answers here as that discourages further answers. Secondly, even if you decided to accept an answer, you should at least wait for several weeks, which is significantly longer than 1 hour. It seems ridiculous to accept a 12 byte answer when there's a 4 byte answer posted only a few hours later.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Trivial challenges get trivial solutions.

```
ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7A&input=MzQ1)

Comment: Trivial challenges meant for noobs like me to try to get into this thing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
IntegerDigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zOvJDU9tcglMz2zpPh/QFFmXomCQ3q0sYlpLBecZ2hkZGgR@/8/AA)

Comment: A surprising builtin. I'm impressed.

Comment: @PinruiHuang I'm impressed too!! how did you think of such an unexpected challenge?

Comment: I thought there weren't enough basic challenges on this site and I'm trying to help newbies like me get into golfing. I snatched it from here:
https://adriann.github.io/programming_problems.html

Comment: @PinruiHuang are you impressed by my answer then?

Comment: Sort of. I'm surprised there's a builtin in this language, but I'm not impressed that a builtin was used. Good job though.

Comment: " I'm surprised there's a builtin in this language"... that's a good one. Welcome to a strange universe!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112134/discussion-between-pinrui-huang-and-j42161217).

Comment: Haaaave you met Mathematica?! https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/58974

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 4 bytes

```
\B
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/xolL5/9/QyMjQwsA) Explanation: Simply inserts a `,` between each pair of digits. Alternatively, if a newline-delimited list is acceptable, then for 3 bytes:

```
!`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fMUHv/39DIyNDCwA) Explanation: Simply lists each digit separately. Alternatively, to produce the example output, then for 13 bytes:

```
\B
, 
^
[
$
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP8aJS0eBK44rmkuFK/b/f2MTUy5DIyNDCwA) Link includes test cases. Alternatively, this can be done in [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1 for 12 bytes:

```
[[|", "]]L`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/Pzq6RklHQSk21idB7/9/YxNTLkMjI0MLAA) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [1 byte](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

Mmm. I have absolutely no idea how I found this...

```
\
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=%5D&input=123)

## Explained

```
  _  The current input (implicit)
 \   Map/Fold by this:
_    The current item of the input, overloaded by \

     Thus, Map/Fold yields a list of the items of the input string.
```

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [2 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
<i
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=%3Ci&input=123)

## Explained

Unpacked: `:!"`

```
_      Input indicator (implicit)
 :!    Split by
   "   The empty string
    "  Trailing quote mark (implicit)
```

Comment: [Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=XA==&input=MzQ1) <- fixed the link for you. I can't believe that works too XD

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 106 bytes

Outputs the digits space-separated.

```
.data
.text
main:li $v0,12
syscall
move $a0,$v0
beq $a0,10,e
li $v0,11
syscall
li $a0,32
syscall
b main
e:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7IzP3/Xy8lsSSRS68ktaKEKzcxM88qJ1NBpcxAx9CIq7iyODkxJ4crN78sVUEl0UAHKM6VlFoIZhsa6KRywdQawtWCRICyxgjdSQogY7lSrf7/NzQyMrQAAA)

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 160 bytes

This outputs in a format looking like a list of digits.

```
.data
.text
main:li $a0,91
li $v0,11
syscall
l:li $v0,12
syscall
move $a0,$v0
beq $a0,10,e
li $v0,11
syscall
li $a0,44
syscall
b l
e:li $a0,93
li $v0,11
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY07CoAwEAX7PYWFZZBstFBvs@oWgY0fEkRPH3@YRrthYN7zs3UxFgMFgiLwFsCRHVuxWU5aNQgXrVohgt99TyIg7etMcm5a@S5ODx0vN6NW/Nc/21WVTJcJcPosv02MaAzWBw)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 4 bytes

Prompts for integer:

```
⍎¨⍕⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6u07tOJR71Sg8H@gwP80LmMTU640LkMjI0MLLgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript(ES6), 38 bytes

Just to kick this off.

```
a=(w)=>{return w.toString().split("")}
```

### Output:

345 -> ["3", "4", "5"]
12218 -> ["1", "2", "2", "1", "8"]

Comment: Wow I got outgolfed so hard so fast that I am literally confused.

Comment: You don't need to count the `a=` and you can remove the parentheses around the `w`, the `return` & the curly braces.

Comment: Oh, and `split` works without and argument and you can cast `w` to a string with `w+""`, but you'll need to wrap it in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 18 bytes

```
lambda x:list(`x`)
```

## Python 3, 21 bytes

```
lambda x:list(str(x))
```

Comment: Great. Can you provide examples of output and put a place where we can run it online?

Comment: If you're allowed to take input as a string, you can have `list` for 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3: <s>28</s> 20 bytes

[Try it Online -  lambda function](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2JzE3KSVRIc8qWqu4pEgjTzP2f0FRZl6JRoWGsYmppiYXjGdoZGRooan5HwA)

[Try it Online -  normal function def](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TaFCI0/TSqtCx7a4pAjItC5KLSktylOo@F9QlJlXolGhYWxiqqnJBeMZGhkZWmhq/gcA)

Tried it with lambda function (20 bytes) instead of normal function definition

```
x=lambda n:[*str(n)]
```

My earlier response with normal def function - 28 bytes

```
def x(n):*x,=str(n);return x
```

Calling the function as follows:

```
print(x(345))
print(x(12218))
```

Output:

```
['3', '4', '5']
['1', '2', '2', '1', '8']
```

Comment: For the lambda function, you are allowed to keep the "x=" part in the header saving 2 bytes: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5foWCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qWqu4pEgjTzP2f0FRZl6JRoWGsYmppiYXjGdoZGRooan5HwA

Comment: Thank You for the tip. I also realized that `` is not working in python 3. It is giving me errors. The tips said i could use `` as an option. That would reduce 3 more

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

Returns a string representation of the integer.

```c
f(i){int*s;asprintf(&s,"%d",i);i=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4xC8IwEIX3/IqjUsm1EW1VEGIGBzdx6Fo7hLaRA02lEQdLf3s9QZzex/Hu8dWLa11Pk5OEA/lnErQNj57JyXlQUdxEilCTCXqcZk3ryLdwKIrT8Swtggz0bjvHuPxRYhGF4H@4W/Ly1VGDMAiA78mWlRlgvdkqyPI828GowN5ab/6LCkgLbruul2RWGmj/LXCmKcJPjK3AQBmH6uIjXiipUsASnIhajNMH)

Comment: We were asked to return a digit array, not a string.

Comment: Suggest `*s;f(i){` instead of `f(i){int*s;`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
jQT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pysw5P9/QyMjQwsA)

Explanation: Takes the integer input (Q) and converts it into base 10 (T) and returns the individual digits in a list.

---

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
cz1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P7nK8P9/Q0MjYxMA)

Unlike the above one, this one takes input as a string and returns an array of the characters of the string. Still 3 bytes. :<)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 1 byte

Another trivial solution.

```
D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l////xiamAA)