# Persistence of a number

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, functional-programming

The [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number) of a number \$x = d_1d_2d_3...d_n\$, with \$d_1 \ne 0\$, under some function \$f : \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0\$ is defined as the number of applications of \$f\$ to the digits of \$x\$ before it reaches a single digit integer. That is, if we have the map

$$I_f: (x = d_1d_2d_3...d_n) \mapsto f(f(...f(d_1, d_2), d_3), ...), d_n),$$

the persistence is defined as

$$P_f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
1 + P_f(I_f(x)), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Some examples include:

- [Additive persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Additive_persistence): \$P_+(2718) = 2\$, \$P_+(5) = 0\$ and \$P_+(2677889) = 3\$
- [Multiplicative persistence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html): \$P_\times(68889) = 7\$, \$P_\times(25) = 2\$ and \$P_\times(8) = 0\$
- Minimal/maximal digit: \$P_{\min}(1734) = 1\$, \$P_{\max}(48203) = 1\$ and \$P_{\min}(5) = 0\$

---

Given a blackbox function \$f : \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0\$ and a positive integer \$x = d_1d_2d_3...d_n\$, where \$d_i\$ are digits with \$d_1 \ne 0\$, output the persistence of \$x\$ under \$f\$.

You may assume that \$f\$ will eventually reach a single digit number when repeatedly applied to \$x\$'s digits.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code wins.

### Test cases

```
f(x, y), x -> output
x + y, 2677889 -> 3
x × y, 68889 -> 7
x ** y, 29 -> 4
φ(x × y), 736 -> 2                 (φ is the Euler Totient function)
x/2 + (x × y), 1234567 -> 5        (using floor division)
|x - y|, 9 -> 0
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1775/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/181958/66833). Brownie points for beating/matching my 7 byte Jelly answer

Comment: what is Euler Totient function?

Comment: @tsh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{#1_(x/.'$:)\}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxdj0FuwjAQRfc+xVQg1XESXByI0yzYcYPuQtRFG7eWUIyIXdkibLkCB+oBuFJtE7VSvZr/5vvPjKhPs+UrtnTxOK+T3Rkh0aRtw0rOq+q59Yq0TVlN9YlQN7Nn379LbIlL0pw9BLZkxWpd8tgYaV7vbO489k5EkcA2A5dkYCHfgDL6YDSykILLYBoWGoVn39cA48yAuEeERF/UK3S74LvLx/GiDJDB/4dvF5AD6M8OtmbfHeFFadn1GoTp37RUfYIsZX6Bv6zpgJC3/o0xg+w/QOyVOsK7/JJD/Dr6M8CNGcSVnn4AYkNXKA==)

Uses `.'$:` instead of `10\` because the latter gives `()` for 0 (and `*/` of `()` is 1), breaking the `(*, 68889)` test case.

```
{#1_(x/.'$:)\}    Curried function, 1st arg: f, 2nd arg: n
    (      )\     repeat and collect starting from n until convergence:
       .'$:         digits
     x/             reduce by x
 #1_              length minus 1
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>70</s> 71 bytes

```python
p=lambda f,n:n>9and-~p(f,(i:=lambda n:f(i(n//10),n%10)if n>9else n)(n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY33QtscxJzk1ISFdJ08qzy7CwT81J06wo00nQ0Mq1gUnlWaRqZGnn6-oYGmjp5qkAyM00BqDY1pzhVIU9TI09TE2LcvoKizLwSjQINqMYKnUqrCu1KHQUjc0MLmCKY3QA)

Takes in an anonymous function `f` and an integer `n`.

---

+1 bytes from [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for noticing an error when `n=0` in `i`.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 65 bytes

```python
p=lambda f,n:~-len(n)and-~p(f,reduce(f,n))
from functools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3HQtscxJzk1ISFdJ08qzqdHNS8zTyNBPzUnTrCjTSdIpSU0qTU4GMPE1NrrSi_FyFtNK85JL8_JxihczcgvyiEi2oQXoFRZl5JRoFGlDjKnQqrYpLijRAghWa2iCqUlNTR8nI3NBCSVMTogvmDAA)

Takes in an anonymous function `f` and a *string* `n` representing an integer.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```
p=lambda f,n:~-len(n)and-~p(f,reduce(f,n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN7UKbHMSc5NSEhXSdPKs6nRzUvM08jQT81J06wo00nSKUlNKk1OBjDxNTagOvYKizLwSjQINqL4KnUqr4pIiDZBghaY2iKrU1NRRMjI3tFCC6YLZBwA)

Same as above. Posted based on the recommendation of [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh).

Comment: You can remove the `from functools import*` by switching to Python 2.

Comment: It looks like the `and/or` in your first solution catches a hitch when getting `n=0`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8A2JzE3KSVRIU0nzyrPzjIxL0W3rkAjTUcj0womBZNQSNPI1MjT1zc00NTJUwWS@UUKeZoaeZqa/wuKMvNKNAo0oDoqdCqtKrQqdRSMTIGSAA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online").  You can [fall back to an if/else](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8A2JzE3KSVRIU0nzyrPzjIxL0W3rkAjTUcj0womlWeVppGpkaevb2igqZOnCiQz0xSAalNzilMV8jQ18jQ1/xcUZeaVaBRoQLVU6FRaVWhV6igYmQIlAQ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") for +1 byte; maybe you see better.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
£‡¥RİL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCI2ODg4OSDOuzJ8KjsiLCLCo+KAocKlUsSwTCIsIiIsIiJd)

Takes inputs from the stack due to technical limits.

```
£      # Store function to register
 ‡--   # Next two elements as a function...
   R   # Reduce by (implicit digits)...
  ¥    # The function stored in the register
    İ  # Apply that function until the result doesn't change, not including the initial value
     L # Count the number of different values.
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCI2ODg4OVxu4oG9KmRcblwiwqhTIiwi4oCh4oGwUsSwTCIsIiIsIiJd) for 5 bytes by setting the input in the header. I think it should be valid

Comment: @lyxal I'd say it isn't really, since it's not something you can do normally.

Comment: It's the equivalent of putting a function into the inputs though. It's setting STDIN. I'll ask in chat

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 38 bytes

```
g->p(n)=if(n>9,1+p(fold(g,digits(n))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY9NDoIwEIWvMmFhWi0LilJYwEWwmhpobUKw4SeBs7ghMcYzcRsLslDiLNppv_feZO4vIyp9VmZ4SIifbSPdcNwoNzGoxLGWqEwi4u0MkrciQ4pkWummtszWoh6FMUWPBLgJmEqXjW2d6eGARCL1OLYn5RgTSFPUEejxRDvYQU-ABoyFYcQt_GbbiQXhH3KaXavvvC3yylw1mp12EvODtfEI1I5coj3q7w8B-9WIS20D3Dkg4nxZcBg-9xs)

A curried function that takes input as `(f)(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Dç/$ƬL’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8f3j6f5fDy/VVjq3xedQw8////2YWFhaWAA)

Takes a function from the previous line and a number from an argument.

```
Dç/$       Convert an integer to its decimal digits and reduce by the input function
    Ƭ      Repeat and collect the results until the results are not unique
           (repeats after reaching a single digit number)
     L’    Get its length minus 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```hs
f#n=sum[1+f#foldl1 f[read[x]|x<-show n]|n>9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctLCoMwGATgfU/xQ7owSha@EoXqRWwKQgwGY1K0jwjePTV0426Yb2bs12nQ2nuJTLO@5y5NJJJWC52C7JahF53ju7uRdbRfMHw3bc393CsDDQh7geeizAuuECUYZZSxqqqBEMhPEmNEq9BDEHaSx/EJ9V@Kk9wdbKSNhPrAkXDi4g2jNMuLkrKwLf0P)

- saved 3 Bytes thanks to @xnor

`#` is an infix function taking the function to apply as *f* and a integer number as *n*.

Uses the trick [shorter conditionals when one outcome is the empty list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150792/84844) combined with a recursive approach by @xnor idea.

If *n* > 9 yeld 1+ result of *#* with number transformed, the result is the sum.

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##TctLCoMwGATgfU/xQ7owSha@EoXqRWwKQgwGY1K0jwjePTV0426Yb2bs12nQ2nuJTLO@5y5NJJJWC52C7JahF53ju7uRdbRfMHw3bc393CsDDQh7geeizAuuECUYZZSxqqqBEMhPEmNEq9BDEHaSx/EJ9V@Kk9wdbKSNhPrAkXDi4g2jNMuLkrKwLf0P "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΔÅ»X.V}θ}N
```

[Assumes the function is defined as a string in variable `X`.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/52210)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/6/9yUw62HdkfohdWe21Hr9/@/FpeZhYWFJQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVQQuj/c1MOtx7aHaEXVntuR63ff53/0dFK2ko6RuaGFrE6YKYplDYyMze3sLAE8bSUdMwsEGwjUygDrOVRw6zD85V0DM2NTZC4JhZGBsZIfLCWXKBeiCGHpyrpmBubgdjFh1ZqHVpndHg70E5DI2MTUzNzkPC5jUo6lrGxAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ       # Apply until the result no longer changes,
        # using the (implicit) input-integer in the first iteration:
 Å»     #  Reduce the digits of the integer by, keeping all intermediate results:
   X    #   Push function-string `X`
    .V  #   Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code
  }θ    #  After the reduce-by: only keep the resulting last value
}N      # After the until-no-more-changes-loop: push the last 0-based index of the loop
        # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Unfortunately, 05AB1E lacks functions, so we'll have to store the 'black box function' in a string and execute it as 05AB1E code with `.V`.
In addition, 05AB1E's regular reduce-by builtin `.»` only works with single builtins (e.g. `.»*`), so we'll have to use the reduce-by that keeps intermediate results and then just keep the final result, in order to have a larger body with multiple builtins (pushing `X`, and executing as 05AB1E `.V` in this case). (e.g. `Å»*}θ`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Black-box function is pre-assigned to variable V, although functions that consist of a single basic operation can be passed via input variable V.

```
@=ìrV)¨A}fÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=CkBYKlk&code=QD3sclYpqEF9ZsQ&input=Njg4ODk)

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 90 bytes

```
X/Y/Z:-Y<10,Z=0;number_codes(Y,A),maplist(plus(48),[F|B],A),foldl(X,B,F,S),X/S/H,Z is H+1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDfToMwGMXv@xS9MWm10ME2wPkn2RKXXS6ZF4DRhUHBJh0ltLgbr309HwkLEubsXc/v@07PaVVLIQtLnXjbhjSi8cKK7p0JiR8md2VzPLB6n8qMKRSRJSbHpBJcaVSJRqFZgMnL@nP12pFcikygkKzImuwwCemObkgMuYKbG8duj00HIxLjhdWr4XVkg0qeLtXoLbSBlnpf1SzrkAFOB4r099rTcWc7OJGkKGpWJJrtEyFQKptSE3Rg@sRYiRyy7RKOtkuyxdjsGy@m9PwyAYoodfENMq5mIDmojOf55YgRUWgZ3HbfQF3P94PglsY2vILWI5wCG5i61Av@qj7o61L3LM1A34b6U2/UXPj/oO@v7lH9zuBTI1gNn6XmrNQwb8pUc1liMBShjjudzT1/NJuPHo3iZQFzIWUNM/7B1bA39KPnUBNg/wA)

90 bytes by Steffan.

Comment: You can use `,` instead of `->`. It will provide multiple choicepoints, but that's fine: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBfb4IwFMXf@RR9WdLOCwoqsL@JJjM@mrgHcNkMQmFNKiW0zJc97@vtI7kWDcr61nNufz3nVrXgorDlgR2PFY4ghg25t@NHdwSbp9FD2ex3tN6mIqMSxzAjsE8qzqTCFW8knoQE3hbf83fj5IJnXCPmsIA1AUNbw5LABjGJlgPXOe4b3n3RqtFt7FiVOPTV@CNyLCXUtqppZixtuMYo0tO1dbs3qzMJkqKoaZEouk04x6loSgV4R9WB0hK7sDIhO@wMVkRnMywq1bSfAMfDoUcGWFP1QLKTGcvz/ogWcWRrW6/N7AI8PwjC8M4g0Q2yn9HY0t2w7gx@2DOC1tC1wbtSJ62q80Ew9i@yh/4f/PtjAqhPil4aTmv0KhSjpUJ5U6aKiZKcSKYWuN54MvWDC2/aYRrJygLlXIgaZeyLye7puTBcpRtZzh8 "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online")

Comment: 90 bytes using operators instead of functions: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDfToMwGMXv@xS9MWm10ME2wPkn2RKXXS6ZF4DRhUHBJh0ltLgbr309HwkLEubsXc/v@07PaVVLIQtLnXjbhjSi8cKK7p0JiR8md2VzPLB6n8qMKRSRJSbHpBJcaVSJRqFZgMnL@nP12pFcikygkKzImuwwCemObkgMuYKbG8duj00HIxLjhdWr4XVkg0qeLtXoLbSBlnpf1SzrkAFOB4r099rTcWc7OJGkKGpWJJrtEyFQKptSE3Rg@sRYiRyy7RKOtkuyxdjsGy@m9PwyAYoodfENMq5mIDmojOf55YgRUWgZ3HbfQF3P94PglsY2vILWI5wCG5i61Av@qj7o61L3LM1A34b6U2/UXPj/oO@v7lH9zuBTI1gNn6XmrNQwb8pUc1liMBShjjudzT1/NJuPHo3iZQFzIWUNM/7B1bA39KPnUBNg/wA "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```ruby
->g,n{n>9?1+f[g,n.digits.reverse.reduce(&g)]:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc5NDoIwEAXgvadoYmKotEUKtGi0HoSwoKUgGyT8GA327FhdaF3NJN97mekn@Viq04JFjdq5Fftz6FeZ3UnZ1M04kF7fdD9oO8tJaW9Tw/ywM0t3aU5YqNkLCVGQqOvUjvPz/lSkVqV3h0dqzGrVgSrDokByLnxpEGWcp@k@B@sgAFhErm@ts9RRwP/47fSHsYP2l8z2c4MAj9g3Qt1@QP3PiZBGccL4N5Q4Ia/AEpJCDgb9Du2WFw)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Expects `(F)(n)`, where `n` is passed as a string. [Returns *false* for *0*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563).

```javascript
F=>g=n=>n>9&&g([...n].map(x=>+x).reduce(F)+'')+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDdboIwFAfwe5/ixEQ8HVBHUYrL2l2YeLcnWHZREPFrhYhb8OlZWy4WF7E3PTnt79@Pg/pRTX7e15dQV5ui24puLWQptJBaLj2vxA9Kqf6kX6rGVki/JfRcbL7zAtfEn06JH3X1bg8CUAdwNLMmICQcwxA8D3BlV1QAmetm8AYrzAJQMLGtF1O8AiPOEvDBRPX1aJRXuqlOBT1VJW4R2wCuLqM1264ExyzhPE2XY0LgZsxmED/ATw4n6T3qMH@Ee83uUYfng9i@rD/dBPA4@Z9gMBvERkoJkf2hv5CIxfNFwm2QwYtB/K4uO6qyxsiwl7fXN/i5@wU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 19 bytes

```
{XXr[}j1ia1jC~qlnfi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dUJwT/786IqIoujbLMDPRMMu5rjAnLy3zf214zn89bQUjM3NzCwtLLj0tBTMLEENLS8EIxI2LS3P2c6ouSMksq82NNsyy1y1I0dMqSFEwNzbjyvKq0NfTyjLS0wcaYWhkbGJqZs6lp5uYpGAJAA)

```
{XX    # As digits
 r[    # Reduce by F
}j1ia  # Insert F before reduce
1jC~   # Evaluate infinitely
qlnfi  # Find first single digit index
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 25 bytes

```
{>9?1+˜´⌽'0'-˜•Fmt;0}
```

Defines a 1-modifier that can be applied to a dyadic function F, turning it into a monadic function that takes a single number and returns its persistence under F. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=X3Ag4oaQIHvwnZWpPjk/MSvwnZWK8J2UvcucwrTijL0nMCcty5zigKJGbXTwnZWpOzB9Cgrii4ZfcCAyOQ==)

#### Explanation

Here  is the original dyadic function,  is the modified function, and  is the single argument of the modified function.

```
{>9?1+˜´⌽'0'-˜•Fmt;0}
{                        }  Block (which is a 1-modifier due to the presence of  in it)
 >9                         Does the argument have multiple digits?
    ?                        If so (recursive case):
                  •Fmt       Format the argument as a string
             '0'-˜            Subtract '0' from each char, giving a list of digits
           ⌽                  Reverse
          ´                   Right fold on:
        ˜                     with reversed arguments
                             Recurse on that value
     1+                       Add one to the result of the recursive call
                       ;0    Otherwise (base case), return 0
```

Unfortunately, BQN doesn't have a left-fold modifier. Scan works left-to-right, but then it costs two bytes to extract the last value from the result list.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 66 bytes

```
(load library
(d P(q((F N)(i(l N 10)0(a 1(P F(foldl F(to-base 10 N
```

Defines a function `P` that takes a function `F` and a number `N` and returns the persistence of `N` under `F`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYk7DsIwEAV7TvHKtwVSYn43SGnlChstSJY2GJKA4tMbU81oZkvP4ml91UrPavA0LbqUAw0j3@SAKEx0RPSddFT0HDHwkd28ccvHSdd7m4i1HbrOkym4owioZgG09A3YEVqYP/7XIiLow@l8ud6k/gA)

#### Explanation

```
(load library
```

The library contains definitions for `foldl` and `to-base`.

```
(d P(q((F N)
```

Define `P` to be a function of two arguments, `F` and `N`.

```
(i(l N 10)0
```

If `N` is less than 10, return 0. Otherwise...

```
(a 1(P F
```

Add 1 to the result of calling `P` recursively on `F` and the result of...

```
(foldl F(to-base 10 N
```

Convert `N` to its base-10 digits and left-fold on `F`.